# Tikz Node with rounded corners

Tags: tikz-pgf

I refer to this question: [LaTeX Photo With Rounded Corners](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61896/latex-photo-with-rounded-corners)

I would like to round the corners of a Tikz node (which actually is a fitted node around two other nodes), but would like to have an additional black frame around it. If I just draw a black rounded frame around my node, it has to be very thick depending on the amount of clipping.

Is there a solution where I first remove the corners and then draw a black frame around the "rounded" node?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4.0cm,outer sep=0pt,clip] (pict) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=4.0cm]{images/black.png}};
    \node [inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4.0cm,outer sep=0pt,clip,below = of pict] (pict2) at (0,0) {\Huge Hello};
    \node[draw=red,thick,fit=(pict)(pict2),rounded corners=.55cm,inner sep=2pt]    {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my own solution. It was heavily inspired by Harish Kumar's answer. I am open for improvements ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0]
    \node [inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (pict)
        {\includegraphics[height=4.0cm]{example-image-a}};
    \node [inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,below = of pict] (pict2)
        {\includegraphics[height=4.0cm]{example-image-b}};              
    \node [draw=red,rounded corners=1pt,line width=3pt,
        inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,fit=(pict)(pict2)] (pict3) {};
    \draw [blue,line width=1pt,rounded corners=1pt]
        ($(pict3.south west)+(\pgflinewidth,\pgflinewidth)$) rectangle
        ($(pict3.north east)-(\pgflinewidth,\pgflinewidth)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 27):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [inner sep=0pt,,outer sep=0pt,clip,rounded corners=0.5cm] (pict) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=4.0cm]{example-image-a}};
   \node[draw=red,thick,fit=(pict),rounded corners=.55cm,inner sep=2pt]    {};

   \node [inner sep=0pt,,outer sep=0pt,clip,rounded corners=0.5cm] (pict1) at (6,0) {\includegraphics[width=5.0cm]{example-image-b}};
   \node[draw=olive,thick,fit=(pict1),rounded corners=.55cm,inner sep=2pt]    {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip [rounded corners=.5cm] (0,0) rectangle (4,8);
    \node [inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4cm,outer sep=0pt] (pict) at (2,6)
         {\includegraphics[height=4.0cm]{example-image-a}};
    \node [draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4cm,outer sep=0pt,clip] (pict2) at (2,2)
         {\includegraphics[height=4.0cm]{example-image-b}};
    \draw [red,line width=1pt,rounded corners=.5cm]
        ([shift={(0.5\pgflinewidth,0.5\pgflinewidth)}]0,0) rectangle
        ([shift={(-0.5\pgflinewidth,-0.5\pgflinewidth)}]4,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok maybe I missed something. Basically I have three nodes. Two are aligned vertically and a third one is fitted around them. The third one is the one which should have the round corners. The problem is, that I cannot use round corners for the inner two nodes, as the upper one is supposed to have only round nodes at the top, and the lower one at the bottom. I added an example to the question.

Comment: Thanks. Your second solution brought me to my own. The problem with your solution (for me) is, that all sizes have to be known in advance. I fit a white node to both inner nodes and then use these coordinates and the calc library for drawing the black border.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is the use of corners of `current bounding box`, form an arc area to fill with a white color to mimic a clip. Changing the `\path` commands to `\draw` commands sees the arc areas.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4.0cm,outer sep=0pt,clip] (pict) at (0,0)  {\includegraphics[width=4.0cm]{example-image-a}};

\path[fill=white] ([yshift=-14pt]current bounding box.north west) -- ++(1,0) arc(90:180:1) --cycle; %<--
\path[fill=white] ([yshift=-14pt]current bounding box.north east) -- ++(-1,0) arc (90:0:1) --cycle; %<--

\node [inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4.0cm,outer sep=0pt,below = of pict,clip] (pict2) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=4.0cm]{example-image-b}};

\path[fill=white] ([yshift=14pt]current bounding box.south west) -- ++(1,0) arc(-90:-180:1) --cycle; %<--
\path[fill=white] ([yshift=14pt]current bounding box.south east) -- ++(-1,0) arc(-90:0:1) -- cycle; %<--

\node[draw=red,thick,fit=(pict)(pict2), rounded corners=.55cm,inner sep=2pt]  {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```