# How to create a rectangle filled with image using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create a rectangle with tikz and fill it with a predefined image.

For example the following line fill the rectangle with a color. How can I fill with my images instead?

```
\fill[color=sthlmRed] (0, 4cm) rectangle(\paperwidth, 0.5\paperheight);
```

Comment: Do you want it also inside `beamer`? Would you mind to provide complete code and not only short snippets? You'll get better answers.

Comment: @Ignasi I think it is a very simple question. I don't have any snippet applicable to my question.
Can you draw a rectangle and fill it with an image?

Comment: Do you want a rectangle filled with tiled copies of the image, a image which get distorted to fill a rectangle, or a clipped one?

Comment: Another option could be `tcbincludegraphics` as is shown in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213405/1952

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following uses TikZ image fill extensions from the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[fill overzoom image=example-image-a] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[fill stretch image=example-image-b] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[fill tile image*={height=3cm}{example-image-c}] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On example c anyway to prevent a small line between the images? I am using this with a texture that should repeat but a small line appears

Comment: @DavidMokonBond There should be no small lines, but maybe, it is a previewer relatex problem? I can only guess...

Comment: yeah no worries, I just tiled it with an external program.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example using `path picture`. You can fill with imported image or with tikz image.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}
\tikzset{
  path image/.style={
    path picture={
      \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {
        \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image}};}},
  path tikzimage/.style={
    path picture={
      \node at (path picture bounding box.center)
        [circle, fill=blue!50, scale=2, text=yellow]{Bravo};}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [path image,draw=blue,thick] (0,1) circle (1);
  \draw [path image,draw=blue,thick] (2,0) rectangle +(2,2);
  \draw [path tikzimage,red,thick] (0,-2) circle (1);
  \draw [path tikzimage,red,thick] (2,-3) rectangle +(2,2);
  \draw [path image, ultra thick, green] (0,-4) to[bend right=90] ++(3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {\includegraphics[]{example-image}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{scope}
    \clip (2,0) rectangle (5cm,8cm);
    \node[anchor=south west] {\includegraphics[]{example-image}};
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun without PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt,dvipsnames,border=0cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\def\M{10}% columns
\def\N{10}% rows
\def\scale{1}% scale
\def\filename{example-image-a}% filename


\def\mygrid{%
    \draw[help lines,red,step=.1,ForestGreen!50](-\M,-\N) grid (\M,\N); 
    \draw[help lines,red,step=1](-\M,-\N) grid (\M,\N);
    \foreach \x in{-\M,...,\M}{\node[anchor=south] at (\x,\N){\x};}
    \foreach \y in{-\N,...,\N}{\node[anchor=east] at (-\M,\y){\y};}
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=\scale,%trim=18mm 12.5mm 15.7mm 15.8mm, clip
]{\filename}}



\newif\ifgrid
\gridtrue
\gridfalse



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0,x=0.5\wd\IBox/\M\relax,y=0.5\ht\IBox/\N\relax]
    \draw[fill=red](-11,-11) rectangle (11,11);
    \node (image) at (0,0) {\usebox\IBox};
    \ifgrid
        \mygrid
    \fi
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]