# "Torn page" decoration for Beamer

Tags: beamer, titles, decorations

I am Basilio, I've been using stackexchange for a while and it's of course really useful.
Here's my first question:
in the thread
[Alternatives to the horizontal line in fancyhdr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113937/alternatives-to-the-horizontal-line-in-fancyhdr)
the user Gonzalo Medina introduces the "torn page" decoration developed by JLDiaz.
Is it possible to use it for the title of a slide in beamer as well?

Thank you very much,
Basilio

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user54427".

Answer (score 7):

This is a possible solution embedding in the `background` template the relevant code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern,tikz,tikzpagenodes}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc,shadows.blur,shadings}
\pgfmathsetseed{1}% do not change this value
% if you change it, please set random offsets accordingly

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113963/13304

\pgfdeclaredecoration{irregular fractal line}{init}
{
  \state{init}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{random*\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}{(random*\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude-0.02)*\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}{0pt}}
  }
}

\tikzset{
   paper/.style={draw=black!10, blur shadow, shade=bilinear interpolation,
                 lower left=black!20, upper left=black!15, upper right=white, lower right=black!10},
   irregular border/.style={decoration={irregular fractal line, amplitude=0.2},
           decorate,
     },
   ragged border/.style={ decoration={random steps, segment length=7mm, amplitude=2mm},
           decorate,
   }
}

% we have to use the background template
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
% test to avoid having the effect in title page
\ifnum\thepage>1%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[orange!30]
        decorate[irregular border]{decorate{decorate{decorate{decorate[ragged border]{
        ($(current page header area.south east-|current page.east) - (0, random*90mm)$) -- ($(current page header area.south west-|current page.west) - (0, random*52mm)$)
        }}}}}
        -- (current page.north west) -- (current page.north east) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}%
\fi%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title}
hello
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]