# Cut bottom of tabular by Zig-Zag pattern (in latex beamer)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, beamer

I try to present a part of a huge table inside the latex beamer environment.
A small part of this table is sufficient to understand what is inside so i decided to indicate the cut-out be a bottom zig-zag line as shown below:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 

\node(elenore)[minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm] 
at (0, 0) { 
\begin{tabular}{c| c c | l }
\cline{2-3}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{comparison} &  \\
 \cline{1-4}
 \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{A} & B & C & \multicolumn{1}{l|} {value} \\
 \cline{1-4}
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{(1,\texttt{X},\texttt{\$},U,11)} & &   (\texttt{a},\texttt{\$},1) & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{C}]$} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{(2,\texttt{r},1,10)} & (\texttt{O},1) & & 
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$H_{1} = [\texttt{aa}]$} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{(3,\texttt{a},\texttt{a},3,2)} & & (\texttt{a},\texttt{a},6) & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$H_5 = [\texttt{yyyyyy}]$} \\    
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{(4,\texttt{a},5,1)} & (\texttt{a},5) & &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$H$ = [\texttt{text}]$} % \\ 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\draw[decoration={zigzag, mirror,segment length=6.25mm}, decorate] (elenore.south west) -- (elenore.south east);
```

My Problem is: how can i stick the zig-zag line perfectly from the beginning of the very left table border to the very right one? Currently it overlaps a little bit what looks quite ugly. Any idea?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The extra padding you are getting is due to the value for `node sep` for the node containg the `tabular`; to get the desired result, you can simply set this to `0pt`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&] 
\node[inner sep=0pt] (elenore)
{%
\begin{tabular}{| c | c c | l |} 
\cline{2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Header} \\
\hline
A & B & C & D \\
E & F & G & H \\
I & J & K & L
\end{tabular}%
};
\draw[decoration={zigzag, mirror,segment length=6mm,amplitude=1.1pt}, decorate] 
  (elenore.south west) -- (elenore.south east);
 \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option would be to draw everything (including the matrix itself) using TikZ:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={rectangle,text width=3em,align=center},
  text depth=0.25ex,
  text height=1.5ex,
  nodes in empty cells
}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&] 
\matrix (elenore) [table] 
{ 
\& \& \& \\
A \& B \& C \& D \\
E \& F \& G \& H \\
I \& J \& K \& L \\
};
\node at ( $ (elenore-1-2)!0.5!(elenore-1-3) $ ) {Header};
\draw
  (elenore-1-2.south west) |- (elenore-1-3.north east) -- (elenore-1-3.south east);
\draw 
  (elenore-4-1.south west) |- (elenore-2-4.north east) -- (elenore-4-4.south east);
\draw[decoration={zigzag, mirror,segment length=6.25mm}, decorate] 
  (elenore-4-1.south west) -- (elenore-4-4.south east);
 \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for the fun of it, here's another possibility using the `pencildraw` style designed by **Ipsen** in [`his answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86164/3954) to [Torn page effect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86150/3954):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={rectangle,text width=3em,align=center},
  text depth=0.25ex,
  text height=1.5ex,
  nodes in empty cells,
  column 4/.style={nodes={align=left}}
  },
pencildraw/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=1.5pt}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&] 
\matrix (elenore) [table] 
{ 
\& \& \& \\
A \& B \& C \& D \\
E \& F \& G \& H \\
I \& J \& K \& L \\
};
\node at ( $ (elenore-1-2)!0.5!(elenore-1-3) $ ) {Header};
\draw
  (elenore-4-2.south west) |- (elenore-1-3.north east) -- (elenore-4-3.south east);
\draw 
  (elenore-4-1.south west) |- (elenore-2-4.north east) -- (elenore-4-4.south east);
\draw[pencildraw] 
  (elenore-4-1.south west) -- (elenore-4-4.south east);
 \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using

```
column <number>/.style={nodes={<options>}}
```

you can change the attributes for nodes in a column; for example, in the code above I used

```
 column 4/.style={nodes={align=left}}
```

to have text aligned left in the fourth column.

Comment: Nice! Is it possible to get the tabular layout {c| c c | l} back? Additionally i have to combine several columns as shown above so i need multicolumn.

Comment: @bobb_the_builder you can use `\multicolumn` directly, but my example shows a convenient replacement (see how "Header" was positioned simulating a `\multicolumn`).

Comment: @Gozalo Medina: both looks pretty good! But i'm still fighting with getting my "old" tabular layout back. I've never expected such an advanced solution as an answer to my quite "simple" question

Comment: @bobb_the_builder please see my updated answer, particularly the last remark about styles for columns.

Comment: @bobb_the_builder oops! A typo! In a comment before I wrote "you can use `\multicolumn` directly"; it should be "you *cannot* use `\multicolumn` directly".

Comment: @Gozalo Medina: yes, i noticed that, no problem. I think i undestood how it works, very good so far. As a little note: it seems that the arydshln package supports "whatever styled" \cline arguments .. that would be also a choice

Comment: @bobb_the_builder please see my updated answer. At the beginning of my edit I've included an option allowing you to use your initial settings (a `tabular` inside a `\node`).

Answer (score 6):

You don't *have* to use tikz

[image]

Your tabular example markup generated a lot of errors so I had to make a few guesses as to the intended cells, but something like

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\sbox0{\begin{tabular}[b]{c| c c | l }
\cline{2-3}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{comparison} &  \\
 \cline{1-4}
 \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{A} & B & C & \multicolumn{1}{l|} {value} \\
 \cline{1-4}
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{(1,\texttt{X},\texttt{\$},U,11)} & &   (\texttt{a},\texttt{\$},1) & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{C} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{(2,\texttt{r},1,10)} & (\texttt{O},1) & & 
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$H_{1} = [\texttt{aa}]$} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{(3,\texttt{a},\texttt{a},3,2)} & & (\texttt{a},\texttt{a},6) & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$H_5 = [\texttt{yyyyyy}]$} \\    
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{(4,\texttt{a},5,1)} & (\texttt{a},5) & &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$H = [\texttt{text}]$}\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
\end{tabular}}%
\usebox0\llap{\resizebox{\wd0}{\height}{\fboxsep0pt\colorbox{white}{\strut${\sim}\!{\sim}\!{\sim}$}}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the correction and for the short,tikz-free solution! The knotted lines are funny looking! I will simply pocket your idea! :-)