# Cut middle of image with zig-zag pattern

Tags: tikz-pgf, crop

I have an image that is too wide to be displayed on a page. I'd like to cut the middle part of the image. The edges should be ragged to help the reader understand that a part is missing.

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using tikz and adjustbox:

```tex
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\newcommand{\cutimage}[3]{
  \adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{
    \tikz{
      \node[inner sep=0pt] (A) {
        \adjustbox{trim={0} {0} {#2\width} {0},clip}{\includegraphics{#1}}
      };
      \draw[decoration={zigzag, mirror,segment length=6mm,amplitude=1.1pt}, decorate](A.north east) -- (A.south east)
    }
    \tikz{
      \node[inner sep=0pt] (A) {
        \adjustbox{trim={#3\width} {0} {0} {0},clip}{\includegraphics{#1}}
      };
      \draw[decoration={zigzag, mirror,segment length=6mm,amplitude=1.1pt}, decorate](A.north west) -- (A.south west)
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```tex
\cutimage{image.png}{.65}{.87}
```

Thanks go out to these answers from which I have borrowed parts:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118305/227949
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52699/227949