# Border with tikz

Tags: tikz-styles

How can i have the same border with tikz[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Which border are you referring to? The border around the orange colored boxes or the double line along the left and bottom margin of the page or something entirely different?

Comment: @NABIL para tikz libraries `decorations.pathmorphing` and `shadows` will surely be a part of it. Then you will need to look for `random steps` and `drop shadow` effects from the tikz manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how complicated you want the solution to be but here is a sarting point, it might be enough for your use else many enhancements are possible

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{%
decorations.pathmorphing,shadows
}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\section{Propriétés Algébriques}
\tikz\node[decoration={random steps,segment length=1cm},decorate,
ultra thick,
draw=orange,fill=orange!20,
inner ysep=5mm,
drop shadow,
anchor=north west,text width=\linewidth]{%
Soient $a$ et $b$ deux réels...
\dotfill

\dotfill
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item hello
\item$\exp\left(a+b\right)=\exp a\times\exp b$
\item world
\item$\exp\left(a-b\right)=\dfrac{\exp a}{\exp b}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\dotfill
};
\end{document}
```

[image]

A very quick solution using `tcolorbox`package :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
decorations.pathmorphing,shadows}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\begin{document}
\tcbset{colback=white,colframe=white,coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=My title,interior titled code={
\filldraw[decoration={random steps,segment length=1cm},decorate,draw=orange,ultra thick, fill=orange!20]
(interior.south west)rectangle(interior.north east);}]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\tcblower
This is the lower part.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting! :) could you take your solution and apply it to the `tcolorbox` package...?

Comment: @cmhughes thank you showing interest. I figured out that you were talking about some `tcolorbox` style integration of my answer ? I have quickly modified an example from `tcolorbox`documentation and got this :

Comment: @cmhughes I added to the answer...

Comment: Looks good. I was thinking you could define a new tcolorbox in the preamble and then use it more simply in the document...

Comment: demonstration of what I was describing: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/272177/6621

Comment: @cmhughes Ok I know what you meant now. For sure one could do it but it was the very first time that I used the `tcolorbox`package :) I am still not very familiar with its settings :)