# How to Rotate a PDF?

Tags: pdf, texlive, rotating

Recently I found out that I can't use Adobe Acrobat to rotate a multi-page pdf file by `.70` degrees.  So I have a regular PDF file (flat scan - no text) that I need to rotate.

But I've [seen a hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586726/rotating-a-pdf-file-by-n-degrees-where-n-is-not-a-multiple-of-90) that you can do it with LaTeX.

The example there isn't enough - it only does one page.

Can I do this with LaTex?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use `pdfpages`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages={-},angle=30]{main}
\end{document}
```

[image: rotated pdf]

Comment: PERFECT!  That is so easy!  You know, you can't even buy pdf software that will do this.  Thanks for answering!

Comment: @BGM It's actually the same solution as the answer you linked to. `pdfpages` passes any keys it doesn't know off to the `\includegraphics` command by default. It can do other things, too, but here it is basically just being used as a wrapper for `\includegraphics`. (I used 30 degrees because I didn't think 0.70 degrees would show up very well in the screenshot ;).)

Comment: That's so awesome!  I spent hours already trying to rotate that pdf! The more I get into LaTeX the happier I become.  Thanks again, cfr.

Comment: @BGM There is ''Adobe InDesign'', but that requires: making a new document of the required size, placing the PDF at 100% size to fit the document (corner to corner), anchoring your adjustments to the center, rotating, and exporting (which includes PDF compatibility and the other fun publication-level stuff). But I could also simplify to: make document of required size, place PDF, rotate around center, export. But if you mean a piece of software ''dedicated'' to rotating a PDF, I doubt you'll find one.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Sounds very complicated ;).

Comment: If you just want to rotate a pdf, you can also use the `pdfjam` wrapper: `pdfjam --outfile rotated.pdf --angle 30 -- input.pdf`.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Yes ... but the point is you can rotate while including it, isn't it?

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question; I came from a non-LaTeX query to this question. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン No problem. `pdfjam` is useful (although I'm still using `pdftk` which is even better, though deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to rotate a .pdf file of one page.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
 \centering
  \includegraphics[width=7.5cm, angle=-90]{graph.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score -10):

If you save the pdf as an image (jpg) and use Microsoft Word you can rotate.

Comment: Hi and welcome, Converting the pdf to jpg will rasterize the graphic, loosing a huge amount of quality. Using Word cannot be the solution in a LaTeX based environment.

Comment: That won't do if the pdf is composed of multiple pages - and it scraps the fonts so that you can't copy text.

Comment: Word is bad. This is a TeX forum.