# The TikZ Game Package – A TeX.SX Project

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun, screenplay

I was wondering if it is possible to write a very simple game in Ti*k*Z; e.g. *(very simple)* Super Mario Bros. Here is Mario:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[step=.5cm] (0,0) grid (8,8);
        \foreach \x in {2.5,3,...,4.5}
        {
            \fill[red] (\x,7.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        }
        \foreach \x in {2,2.5,...,6}
        {
            \fill[red] (\x,7) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        }
        \foreach \x in {2,2.5,3}
        {
            \fill[brown!70!black] (\x,6.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        }
        \foreach \x in {3.5,4}
        {
            \fill[yellow!50!orange] (\x,6.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        }
        \fill[black] (4.5,6.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        \fill[yellow!50!orange] (5,6.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[brown!70!black] (1.5,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[yellow!50!orange] (2,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[brown!70!black] (2.5,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[yellow!50!orange] (3,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[yellow!50!orange] (3.5,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[yellow!50!orange] (4,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[black] (4.5,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[yellow!50!orange] (5,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[yellow!50!orange] (5.5,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[yellow!50!orange] (6,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-.5)}]
            \fill[brown!70!black] (1.5,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[yellow!50!orange] (2,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[brown!70!black] (2.5,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[brown!70!black] (3,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[yellow!50!orange] (3.5,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[yellow!50!orange] (4,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[yellow!50!orange] (4.5,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[black] (5,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[yellow!50!orange] (5.5,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[yellow!50!orange] (6,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[yellow!50!orange] (6.5,6) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        \end{scope}
        \fill[brown!70!black] (2,5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        \foreach \x in {2.5,3,...,4}
        {
            \fill[yellow!50!orange] (\x,5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        }
        \foreach \x in {4.5,5,...,6}
        {
            \fill[black] (\x,5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        }
        \foreach \x in {2.5,3,...,5}
        {
            \fill[yellow!50!orange] (\x,4.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        }
        \foreach \x in {2,2.5,...,5.5}
        {
            \fill[red] (\x,4) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        }
        \fill[blue] (3,4) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        \fill[blue] (4.5,4) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-.5)}]
            \foreach \x in {1.5,2,...,6}
            {
                \fill[red] (\x,4) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            }
            \fill[blue] (3,4) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[blue] (4.5,4) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-1)}]
            \foreach \x in {1,1.5,2,...,6.5}
            {
                \fill[red] (\x,4) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            }
            \fill[blue] (3,4) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[blue] (3.5,4) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[blue] (4,4) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[blue] (4.5,4) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        \end{scope}
        \fill[yellow!50!orange] (1,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        \fill[yellow!50!orange] (1.5,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[red] (2,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[blue] (2.5,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[yellow!50!orange] (3,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[blue] (3.5,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[blue] (4,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[yellow!50!orange] (4.5,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[blue] (5,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[red] (5.5,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[yellow!50!orange] (6,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[yellow!50!orange] (6.5,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        \foreach \x in {1,1.5,2}
        {
            \fill[yellow!50!orange] (\x,2) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        }
        \foreach \x in {2.5,3,...,5}
        {
            \fill[blue] (\x,2) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        }
        \fill[yellow!50!orange] (5.5,2) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        \fill[yellow!50!orange] (6,2) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        \fill[yellow!50!orange] (6.5,2) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-1)}]
            \fill[yellow!50!orange] (1,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            \fill[yellow!50!orange] (1.5,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[blue] (2,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[blue] (2.5,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                    \fill[blue] (3,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[blue] (3.5,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[blue] (4,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                    \fill[blue] (4.5,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[blue] (5,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                \fill[blue] (5.5,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                    \fill[yellow!50!orange] (6,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                    \fill[yellow!50!orange] (6.5,2.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        \end{scope}
            \foreach \x in {2,2.5,3}
            {
                \fill[blue] (\x,1) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            }
        \begin{scope}[shift={(2.5,0)}]
            \foreach \x in {2,2.5,3}
            {
                \fill[blue] (\x,1) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            }
        \end{scope}
        \foreach \x in {1.5,2,2.5}
        {
            \fill[brown!70!black] (\x,.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
        }
        \begin{scope}[shift={(3.5,0)}]
            \foreach \x in {1.5,2,2.5}
            {
                \fill[brown!70!black] (\x,.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            }
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-.5)}]
            \foreach \x in {1,1.5,2,2.5}
            {
                \fill[brown!70!black] (\x,.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
            }
            \begin{scope}[shift={(4,0)}]
                \foreach \x in {1,1.5,2,2.5}
                {
                    \fill[brown!70!black] (\x,.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
                }
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

And here is the original:

[image: Screenshot]

Because you can create simple animations and controls in Ti*k*Z (see the Rubiks thread), it is maybe possible to generate a world (e.g. from Mario)     , which is refreshed by some buttons.

For the beginn the pong game would be absolutely enough I think, because it is really hard to implement such things especially in Ti*k*Z.

As the title says, it would sound *great* if something like that would exist, so my question is: Does anybody have an idea how to do that? This is not a do-it-for-me – question, rather collecting ideas.

Comment: LaTeX will always produce pdf files I think. So if you want to produce a game, you'd have to create pdfs for all possible outcomes beforehand. Not sure if that would be fun. (+1 for the Mario ;-)

Comment: @marmot: Yes, that's right, but I thought just like an interactive-animation-thing, you know? And thank you! ;)

Comment: The animate package has controls. I guess the user who could help you most is @AlexG, who was recently on the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends), meaning you could ping him there. He managed to do a really nice animation in which two ducks got exchanged when one clicked on them.

Comment: Interesting idea. Pkg `animate`, however, might not be the right tool here, as it does not allow branching. But PDF Layers (OCGs) could be an option (#pixels x #colours), to be enabled/hidden by JavaScript, possibly using random numbers, and/or by buttons.

Comment: @marmot not, quite. Standard LaTeX output file is `.dvi` (and I think `.ps`), while `pdflatex` output file's `.pdf`.

Comment: @naphaneal Well, technically I agree but your probably know what I wanted to say, don't you? Even more explicitly: LaTeX will create a static document.

Comment: A non-trivial game could be a puzzle: reorder previously shuffled cells to show Mario again by moving sub-rows and sub-columns towards a whole (Sliding Puzzle).

Comment: @AlexG: This is great! Is maybe Tetris possible?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/510755/128553

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Sliding Puzzle

(Acrobat Reader required; `pdflatex` or `lualatex`)

This is a non-trivial game with user interaction, based on PDF Layers (OCGs, package **`ocgx2`**).

The picture is split into 15 tiles, stacked upon each other for every cell of the puzzle board, each on an individual PDF Layer. The total number of PDF Layers is thus 4 x 4 x 15 = 240. Their visibility is controlled by JavaScript, triggered by clicking on an array of transparent buttons overlaid on top of the puzzle board.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xsavebox}
\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}
\usepackage{media9} % \mediabutton

\usepackage{tikzmarmots}
\usepackage{xcolor}\pagecolor{gray}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex\def\pdfpageattr{\pdfvariable pageattr}\fi

\begin{xlrbox}{Marmot}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1,transform shape]
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (4.4,4.4);
    \node at (current bounding box.center) {\tikz\marmot[scale=2.1];};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{xlrbox}

%generating tiles Marmot.1, ..., Marmot.15
\multido{\nX=0.0+1.1,\iI=0+1}{4}{
  \multido{\nY=3.3+-1.1,\iJ=0+1}{4}{
    \ifnum\numexpr\iI+\iJ\relax>0
      \begin{xlrbox}{Marmot.\the\numexpr\iI+\iJ*4\relax}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \useasboundingbox (\nX,\nY) rectangle ++(1.1,1.1);
          \clip (\nX,\nY) rectangle ++(1.1,1.1);
          \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=south west,fill=white] at (0,0) {\theMarmot};
        \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{xlrbox}
    \fi
  }
}

\newcommand\MyStatus[2]{\ifnum#1=#2 visible\else invisible\fi}

%initialisations (JavaScript) on page-open (/O <<...>>)
\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup
  \pdfpageattr{
    \the\pdfpageattr
    /AA << /O << /S/JavaScript /JS (%
      var tile=new Array(4);
      var oldTile=new Array(4);
      for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
        tile[i]=new Array(4);
        oldTile[i]=new Array(4);
        for(var j=0;j<4;j++){
          tile[i][j]=new Array(15);
          oldTile[i][j]=i+j*4-1;
        }
      }
      ocg=this.getOCGs(this.pageNum);
      for(var i in ocg){
        ocgName=ocg[i].name.split('.');
        tile[ocgName[0]][ocgName[1]][ocgName[2]-1]=ocg[i];
      }%
      var swap_i=0; var swap_j=0;
      var onButtonClick=function(i,j){
        if(swap_i==i && swap_j!=j){
          for(var jj=swap_j; jj!=j; swap_j<j ? jj++ : jj--){
            if(jj!=swap_j) tile[i][jj][oldTile[i][jj]].state=false;
            newTile=oldTile[i][swap_j<j ? jj+1 : jj-1];
            oldTile[i][jj]=newTile;
            tile[i][jj][newTile].state=true;
          }
        } else if(swap_j==j && swap_i!=i){
          for(var ii=swap_i; ii!=i; swap_i<i ? ii++ : ii--){
            if(ii!=swap_i) tile[ii][j][oldTile[ii][j]].state=false;
            newTile=oldTile[swap_i<i ? ii+1 : ii-1][j];
            oldTile[ii][j]=newTile;
            tile[ii][j][newTile].state=true;
          }
        }
        if(swap_i==i || swap_j==j){
          if(oldTile[i][j]>-1)
            tile[i][j][oldTile[i][j]].state=false;
          oldTile[i][j]=-1;
          swap_i=i; swap_j=j;
        }
      };
    ) >> >>
  }
}
\x

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \multido{\nX=0.0+1.1,\iI=0+1}{4}{%
    \multido{\nY=3.3+-1.1,\iJ=0+1}{4}{%
      %tiles
      \multido{\iK=1+1}{15}{%
        \begin{scope}[ocg={ref=\iI.\iJ.\iK,status=\MyStatus{\the\numexpr\iI+\iJ*4\relax}{\iK}}]%
          \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=south west] at (\nX,\nY) {\xusebox{Marmot.\iK}};
        \end{scope}
      }
      %button array
      \draw[
        line width=0,
        postaction={
          path picture={
            \path (path picture bounding box.south west) coordinate (p1)
              (path picture bounding box.north east) coordinate (p2)
              (p1) node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west,outer sep=0pt] {%
                \mediabutton[jsaction={try{onButtonClick(\iI,\iJ);}catch(e){}}]{%
                  \tikz \useasboundingbox (p1) rectangle (p2);%
                }%
              };
          }
        }
      ] (\nX,\nY) rectangle ++(1.1,1.1);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

## Original Answer

For this kind of games based on a pixel array using a given set of pre-defined colours, the TikZ-part is straightforward to be implemented; making use of package **`ocgx2`**, we simply put each pixel colour on an individual PDF Layer.

The whole logic of the game can then be implemented in JavaScript. It programmatically controls the visibility of each pixel colour.

As a trivial example, we implement a "game" whose sole purpose is to shuffle the pixel colours by pressing a button and to enjoy the result (**Acrobat Reader** or **Foxit** required for viewing):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}
\usepackage{media9} % \mediabutton

\newcommand{\mycolour}[1]{\ifcase#1
white%0
\or
black%1
\or
red%2
\or
orange%3
\or
blue%4
\or
brown%5
\or
yellow%6
\fi}

\begin{document}

%set up canvas (16x16 pixels^2) x (7 colours)
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \X in {0,1,...,15} {
    \foreach \Y in {0,1,...,15} {
      \foreach \Z in {0,1,...,6} {
        \begin{scope}[ocg={ref=\X.\Y.\Z,status=invisible}]
          \node[minimum size=0.5cm,draw,fill=\mycolour{\Z}] at (\X/2,-\Y/2){};
        \end{scope}
      }
    }
  }
  \node at (3.75,-8) {%
    \mediabutton[
      jsaction={
        %initialisation
        if(typeof pixelcolour==='undefined'){
          var pixelcolour=new Array(16);
          var oldcolour=new Array(16);
          for(var i=0;i<16;i++){
            pixelcolour[i]=new Array(16);
            oldcolour[i]=new Array(16);
            for(var j=0;j<16;j++){
              pixelcolour[i][j]=new Array(7);
              oldcolour[i][j]=0;
            }
          }
          ocg=this.getOCGs(this.pageNum);
          for(i in ocg){
            ocgName=ocg[i].name.split('.');
            pixelcolour[ocgName[0]][ocgName[1]][ocgName[2]]=ocg[i];
          }  
        }
        %randomise colours
        for(i=0;i<16;i++){
          for(j=0;j<16;j++){
            newcolour=Math.floor(Math.random()*7);
            pixelcolour[i][j][oldcolour[i][j]].state=false;
            pixelcolour[i][j][newcolour].state=true;
            oldcolour[i][j]=newcolour;
          }
        }
      }
    ]{\fbox{Random}}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! But how long does it take to compile? I'm compiling since ten minutes …

Comment: Are you on a RaspberryPi :-)? Yes, it takes a while. 20 seconds on my PC.

Comment: Yes, I am, but it doesn't work. Could you post a little ```.gif```?

Comment: Trying to upload a static PNG, but imgur rejects it for some reason.

Comment: You could actually do a small screen recording and then convert the ```.mp4``` (or ```.avi```) to a ```.gif```.

Comment: @AlexG Can you add a picture, please?

Comment: @Sebastiano Pictures and a new game added :-).

Comment: @AlexG Great! Very gooood :-)

Comment: This is incredible work. How could one take out the black lines between the tiles? I want to hide a puzzle like this in one of the figures in my dissertation. :-)

Comment: @jvriesem That's easy. Look for the single `\draw` in the code and replace it with `\path`. Though I personally would keep the lines for this kind of game.

Comment: Thanks! I actually embedded this as an Easter egg in one of the figures in my dissertation (rather than the marmot image here). As in this example, clicking on the figure in the right place would start the game. I want to get it past the proofreaders, so I need to keep it hidden. The figure has a white background, so I made the game above have a white background, and I adjusted a label or two so that the "missing piece" is not visible by default. It is not visible when printing it, either. Only problem is the 9x4 grid makes the figure look blocky when scrolling past it quickly. Dunno why!

Comment: @jvriesem Funny idea. Hope the referees take it with humor if they happen to discover the Easter egg. As for the loading speed, I think it is quite natural that the PDF reader wants to prerender the whole stack of 36*35=1260 layers of the image and also the OCG information when scrolling over the page, which may take some time. I just wonder whether it needs to do so on every re-visiting the page, or whether it uses some kind of cache for the pages seen.

Comment: @AlexG: Eeep — so it IS that many layers! That makes sense. It's also a high resolution figure (7000x3000 pixels, <1 MB PNG file), so that probably doesn't help.... Fortunately, the "game" doesn't hurt the PDF size...almost at all! (I can't imagine the university proofreaders will notice. I plan to publish part of the dissertation content but not include the game for the subsequent publication, where somebody would *definitely* notice!)

Comment: @AlexG: Update: the game made it through the [final published version](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/qe863w/using_tikz_i_embedded_a_hidden_playable_game_in/)! It doesn't seem to have any visual glitches or performance issues now, so perhaps the PDF reader updated how it handles these things in the past year.

Answer (score 12):

Four steps with Super Mario.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\newcommand{\MarioStop}{
\fill[red] (2.5,8) -- (5,8) -- (5,7.5) -- (6.5,7.5) -- (6.5,7) -- (2,7) -- (2,7.5) -- (2.5,7.5);
\fill[brown!70!black] (2,7) -- (3.5,7) -- (3.5,6.5) -- (3,6.5) -- (3,6) -- (3.5,6) -- (3.5,5.5) -- (2.5,5.5) -- (2.5,6.5) -- (2,6.5);
\fill[brown!70!black] (4.5,7) -- (4.5,6) -- (5,6) -- (5,7);
\fill[brown!70!black](5,6) -- (5.5,6) -- (5.5,5.5) -- (6.5,5.5) -- (6.5,5) -- (4.5,5) -- (4.5,5.5) -- (5,5.5);
\fill[brown!70!black] (1.5,6.5) -- (2,6.5) -- (2,5.5) -- (2.5,5.5) -- (2.5,5) -- (1.5,5);
\fill[yellow!50!orange] (3.5,7) -- (4.5,7) -- (4.5,6) -- (5,6) -- (5,5.5) -- (4.5,5.5) -- (4.5,5) -- (6,5) -- (6,4.5) -- (2.5,4.5) -- (2.5,5.5) -- (3.5,5.5) -- (3.5,6) -- (3,6) -- (3,6.5) -- (3.5,6.5);
\fill[yellow!50!orange] (2,6.5) -- (2.5,6.5) -- (2.5,5.5) -- (2,5.5);
\fill[yellow!50!orange] (5,7) -- (5.5,7) -- (5.5,6.5) -- (6.5,6.5) -- (6.5,6) -- (7,6) -- (7,5.5) -- (5.5,5.5) -- (5.5,6) -- (5,6);
\fill[red] (2,4.5) -- (3,4.5) -- (3,3) -- (2.5,3) -- (2.5,2.5) -- (2,2.5) -- (2,3) -- (1,3) -- (1,3.5) -- (1.5,3.5) -- (1.5,4) -- (2,4);
\fill[red] (3.5,4.5) -- (5.5,4.5) -- (5.5,4) -- (6.5,4) -- (6.5,3.5) -- (7,3.5) -- (7,3) -- (6,3) -- (6,2.5) -- (5.5,2.5) -- (5.5,3) -- (5,3) -- (5,4) -- (4.5,4) -- (4.5,3.5) -- (3.5,3.5);
\fill[blue] (3,4.5) -- (3.5,4.5) -- (3.5,3.5) -- (4.5,3.5) -- (4.5,4) -- (5,4) -- (5,3) -- (5.5,3) -- (5.5,2) -- (6,2) -- (6,1) -- (4.5,1) -- (4.5,1.5) -- (3.5,1.5) -- (3.5,1) -- (2,1) -- (2,2) -- (2.5,2) -- (2.5,3) -- (3,3);
\fill[yellow!50!orange] (3,3) -- (3.5,3) -- (3.5,2.5) -- (3,2.5);
\fill[yellow!50!orange] (4.5,3) -- (5,3) -- (5,2.5) -- (4.5,2.5);
\fill[yellow!50!orange] (6,3) -- (7,3) -- (7,1.5) -- (6,1.5) -- (6,2) -- (5.5,2) -- (5.5,2.5) -- (6,2.5);
\fill[yellow!50!orange] (1,3) -- (2,3) -- (2,2.5) -- (2.5,2.5) -- (2.5,2) -- (2,2) -- (2,1.5) -- (1,1.5);
\fill[brown!70!black] (1.5,1) -- (3,1) -- (3,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,0.5) -- (1.5,0.5);
\fill[brown!70!black] (5,1) -- (6.5,1) -- (6.5,0.5) -- (7,0.5) -- (7,0) -- (5,0);
}
\newcommand{\MarioFStep}{
\fill[red] (3,7.5) -- (5.5,7.5) -- (5.5,7) -- (7,7) -- (7,6.5) -- (2.5,6.5) -- (2.5,7) -- (3,7);
\fill[brown!70!black] (2.5,6.5) -- (4,6.5) -- (4,6) -- (3.5,6) -- (3.5,5.5) -- (4,5.5) -- (4,5) -- (3,5) -- (3,6) -- (2.5,6);
\fill[brown!70!black] (2,6) -- (2.5,6) -- (2.5,5) -- (3,5) -- (3,4.5) -- (2,4.5);
\fill[brown!70!black] (5,6.5) -- (5,5.5) -- (5.5,5.5) -- (5.5,6.5);
\fill[brown!70!black] (5.5,5.5) -- (6,5.5) -- (6,5) -- (7,5) -- (7,4.5) -- (5,4.5) -- (5,5) -- (5.5,5);
\fill[brown!70!black] (1.5,2.5) -- (2.5,2.5) -- (2.5,2) -- (2,2) -- (2,1) -- (1.5,1) -- (1.5,0.5) -- (1,0.5) -- (1,1.5) -- (1.5,1.5);
\fill[brown!70!black] (3.5,1) -- (5,1) -- (5,0.5) -- (5.5,0.5) -- (5.5,0) -- (3.5,0);
\fill[yellow!50!orange]  (2.5,6) -- (3,6) -- (3,5) -- (2.5,5);
\fill[yellow!50!orange] (4,6.5) -- (5,6.5) -- (5,5.5) -- (5.5,5.5) -- (5.5,5) -- (5,5) -- (5,4.5) -- (6.5,4.5) -- (6.5,3.5) -- (7,3.5) -- (7,3) -- (6.5,3) -- (6.5,2.5) -- (5.5,2.5) -- (5.5,3.5) -- (6,3.5) -- (6,4) -- (3,4) -- (3,5) -- (4,5) -- (4,5.5) -- (3.5,5.5) -- (3.5,6) -- (4,6);
\fill[yellow!50!orange]  (5.5,6.5) -- (6,6.5) -- (6,6) -- (7,6) -- (7,5.5) -- (7.5,5.5) -- (7.5,5) -- (6,5) -- (6,5.5) -- (5.5,5.5);
\fill[yellow!50!orange] (2,3.5) -- (2.5,3.5) -- (2.5,2.5) -- (1.5,2.5) -- (1.5,3) -- (2,3);
\fill[red] (2.5,4) -- (4.5,4) -- (4.5,3.5) -- (5,3.5) -- (5,4) -- (5.5,4) -- (5.5,2.5) -- (3,2.5) -- (3,3) -- (2.5,3);
\fill[blue] (4.5,4) -- (4.5,3.5) -- (5,3.5) -- (5,4);
\fill[blue] (2.5,3) -- (3,3) -- (3,2.5) -- (6,2.5) -- (6,1.5) -- (5.5,1.5) -- (5.5,1) -- (4,1) -- (4,1.5) -- (3.5,1.5) -- (3.5,1) -- (2,1) -- (2,2) -- (2.5,2);
}
\newcommand{\MarioSStep}{
\fill[red] (3,8) -- (5.5,8) -- (5.5,7.5) -- (7,7.5) -- (7,7) -- (2.5,7) -- (2.5,7.5) -- (3,7.5);
\fill[red] (1.5,4.5) -- (3.5,4.5) -- (3.5,3) -- (2.5,3) -- (2.5,3.5) -- (1.5,3.5);
\fill[red] (4.5,4.5) -- (5.5,4.5) -- (5.5,4) -- (6.5,4) -- (6.5,3.5) -- (7,3.5) -- (7,3) -- (6,3) -- (6,3.5) -- (5,3.5) -- (5,4) -- (4.5,4);
\fill[brown!70!black] (2.5,7) -- (4,7) -- (4,6.5) -- (3.5,6.5) -- (3.5,6) -- (4,6) -- (4,5.5) -- (3,5.5) -- (3,6.5) -- (2.5,6.5);
\fill[brown!70!black]  (2,6.5) -- (2.5,6.5) -- (2.5,5.5) -- (3,5.5) -- (3,5) -- (2,5);
\fill[brown!70!black]  (5,7) -- (5,6) -- (5.5,6) -- (5.5,7);
\fill[brown!70!black]  (5.5,6) -- (6,6) -- (6,5.5) -- (7,5.5) -- (7,5) -- (5,5) -- (5,5.5) -- (5.5,5.5);
\fill[brown!70!black]  (1,1.5) -- (2,1.5) -- (2,1) -- (2.5,1) -- (2.5,0.5) -- (3,0.5) -- (3,0) -- (1.5,0) -- (1.5,0.5) -- (1,0.5);
\fill[brown!70!black]  (6.5,2.5) -- (7,2.5) -- (7,3) -- (7.5,3) -- (7.5,1) -- (6.5,1);
\fill[yellow!50!orange] (4,7) -- (5,7) -- (5,6) -- (5.5,6) -- (5.5,5.5) -- (5,5.5) -- (5,5) -- (6.5,5) -- (6.5,4.5) -- (3,4.5) -- (3,5.5) -- (4,5.5) -- (4,6) -- (3.5,6) -- (3.5,6.5) -- (4,6.5);
\fill[yellow!50!orange] (2.5,6.5) -- (3,6.5) -- (3,5.5) -- (2.5,5.5);
\fill[yellow!50!orange] (5.5,7) -- (6,7) -- (6,6.5) -- (7,6.5) -- (7,6) -- (7.5,6) -- (7.5,5.5) -- (6,5.5) -- (6,6) -- (5.5,6);
\fill[yellow!50!orange] (0.5,4) -- (1.5,4) -- (1.5,3.5) -- (2,3.5) -- (2,3) -- (1.5,3) -- (1.5,2.5) -- (0.5,2.5);
\fill[yellow!50!orange] (6.5,4) -- (8,4) -- (8,3) -- (7,3) -- (7,3.5) -- (6.5,3.5);
\fill[blue] (3.5,4.5) -- (4.5,4.5) -- (4.5,4) -- (5,4) -- (5,3.5) -- (6,3.5) -- (6,2.5) -- (6.5,2.5) -- (6.5,1) -- (5,1) -- (5,1.5) -- (3.5,1.5) -- (3.5,1) -- (2,1) -- (2,1.5) -- (1.5,1.5) -- (1.5,2) -- (2,2) -- (2,2.5) -- (2.5,2.5) -- (2.5,3) -- (3.5,3);
\fill[yellow!50!orange] (4,3.5) -- (4.5,3.5) -- (4.5,3) -- (4,3);
}
\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop,
    begin={\begin{tikzpicture}},
    end={\end{tikzpicture}}]{2}
\MarioStop\newframe
\MarioFStep\newframe
\MarioSStep\newframe
\MarioFStep\newframe
\MarioSStep\newframe
\MarioFStep\newframe
\MarioSStep\newframe
\MarioFStep\newframe
\MarioSStep\newframe
\MarioStop
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

[image: Super Mario Four Steps]

Comment: Can you add a picture, please?

Comment: @Sebastiano It's an easy animation of Super Mario that make four steps.

Comment: It is very nice to see the animation. :-). However +1.

Comment: Someone knows how to get the translation when mario walk.

Comment: looks like a lot of work. +1.