# Javascript application in latex

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if it is possible to add an interactive app created with Javascript to a Latex document.

I would like to add some of the Javascripts that appear [here](https://fredhohman.com/card-shuffling/?fbclid=IwAR3YYzeYjVYXDUt1oSglTOaUbFPU3EGjcY960Dk_-5Q1mrz61sypN-EGrvQ).

Like that one:

[image]

**EDIT**

I can have the .js document, so I would like how to attach a .js to Latex.

Any idea? Any help?

Comment: Not wishing to dissuade other answers since your Question is GOOD. First off that page just like millions of others does not work for me, Why ? because it needs a mechanism that can be easily and is all too frequently exploited so my browser will not view it, Ok others will reply they can view it fine since that's a browser issue not a LaTeX PDF with JavaScript, However if you manage to add such code to your output PDF I will still not be able to view it **Even if I open it in my insecure Acrobat Viewer** which I don't normally use. Bottom line look for answers other than fixing on  JavaScript

Comment: Yes, this one would be possible with PDF-Layers (OCGs), as can be created with package `ocgx2`, and JavaScript. Look at this example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444956 Of course, a completely different logic would have to be implemented in JavaScript.

Comment: And what about if I have the .js document?

Comment: @idriskameni you can copy the contents of the .js document into your LaTeX source, similar to the linked question.

Comment: Will the app apear if I just copy the code?

Comment: It is probably not as simple as that, Javascript for PDF files is not the same as Javascript for web pages in terms of the interaction between the document and the code. But if you know where and how to put it you can copy parts of the code. I realize that the 'where and how to put it' is part of your question, you can try asking a more specific question here with an example document, or ask on Stack Overflow (here on TeX.SE there are not many people that know about JavaScript, because it is not used a lot for LaTeX and it has very limited viewer support).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ports the card shuffling example to LaTeX and PDF, using PDF Layers (package `ocgx2`) and JavaScript. Acrobat Reader is required for display.

**Update**: Extended example with chart that plots King-diamond position versus riffle count.

*Warning:* It takes about 2h to compile the code twice using `pdflatex` due to the large number of OCGs (around 21k) that is created. Moreover, for `pdflatex` to run successfully, the `main_memory` must be increased in the format, or `lualatex` to be used instead. The (original) example without the chart compiles much faster (second code box).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}

\usepackage{tikz,color,calc}
\usepackage{media9} %\mediabutton
\usepackage{xsavebox,ocgx2}

%suit symbols from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9643
\DeclareSymbolFont{extraup}{U}{zavm}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varheart}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{86}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vardiamond}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{87}

%typesets playing card; args: value, suite, colour
\makeatletter
\def\mycard#1#2#3{%
  \fbox{\rule[-4ex]{0pt}{5ex}\makebox[3.5ex][l]{#1$\color{#3}\@nameuse{#2}$}}}
\makeatother

%initialisations (JavaScript) on page-open (/O <<...>>), reset on page-close
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex\def\pdfpageattr{\pdfvariable pageattr}\fi
\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup
  \pdfpageattr{
    \the\pdfpageattr
    /AA <<
      /O << /S/JavaScript /JS (%
%        console.show();
        console.clear();
        %riffle top card
        var riffle=function(){
          for(var i=0;i<52;i++) oldOrder[i]=order[i];
          if(order[0]!=51){
            %remove current card from top
            var top=order.shift();
            %insert `top' at new random position
            order.splice(1+Math.random()*order.length, 0, top);
            %new King Diamond position
            KdiamondPos=order.indexOf(51);
            ++riffleCount;
            console.println(riffleCount+' '+KdiamondPos);
          }
        };
        var update=function(){
          %update OCG visibility
          for(tablePos=0;tablePos<52;tablePos++){
            try{card[tablePos][oldOrder[tablePos]].state=false;}catch(e){}
            try{card[tablePos][order[tablePos]].state=true;}catch(e){}
          }
          try{pix[riffleCount][KdiamondPos].state=true;}catch(e){}
        };
        var reset=function(){
          console.clear();
          try{app.clearInterval(myIntA);}catch(e){}
          try{app.clearInterval(myIntB);}catch(e){}
          for(var i=0;i<52;i++) {oldOrder[i]=order[i]; order[i]=i;}
          riffleCount=0; KdiamondPos=51;
          for(var j=0;j<52;j++){
            for(var i=0;i<350;i++){
              try{pix[i][j].state=false;}catch(e){}
            }
          }
          update(); 
        };
        %card[<table position>][<stack position>]
        var card=new Array(52);
        for(var i=0;i<52;i++){card[i]=new Array(52);}
        %pix[<riffle count>][<stack position>]
        var pix=new Array(350);
        for(var i=0;i<350;i++){pix[i]=new Array(52);}
        ocg=this.getOCGs(this.pageNum);
        for(var i in ocg){
          ocgName=ocg[i].name.split('-');
          if(ocgName[2]=='card')
            card[ocgName[0]][ocgName[1]]=ocg[i];
          else % 'pix'
            pix[ocgName[0]][ocgName[1]]=ocg[i];
        }%
        %initial order
        var order=new Array(52); for(var i=0;i<52;i++) order[i]=i;
        var oldOrder=new Array(52);
        var riffleCount=0, KdiamondPos=51;
      ) >>
      /C << /S/JavaScript /JS (reset();) >>
    >>
  }
}
\x

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}\parindent=0pt%
%
% build chart
\xsavebox{Pix}[0.317mm][c]{\tikz\fill (0,0) circle [radius=0.5mm];}
\parbox{\linewidth}{\offinterlineskip%
  $\uparrow$ K$\color{red}\vardiamond$ position\\[0.5ex]
  \makebox[111mm]{\hrulefill}\\
    \foreach \j in {0,...,51}{%
      \foreach \i in {0,...,349}{%
         \expandafter\ifnum\numexpr\j+\i\relax<51
           \phantom{\thePix}%
         \else%  
           \begin{ocg}{\i-\j-pix}{\i-\j-pix}{off}%
             \thePix%
           \end{ocg}%
         \fi% 
      }\\
    }%
  \makebox[111mm]{\hrulefill}\\[0.5ex]
  \makebox[111mm][r]{riffle count $\rightarrow$}%
  \begin{ocg}{0-51-pix}{0-51-pix}{on}\end{ocg}%
}\\[1ex]

%typeset playing cards into xsaveboxes
\foreach \suit/\suitcol in {%
  spadesuit/black,clubsuit/black,varheart/red,vardiamond/red}{%
  \fboxrule=0.5pt\fboxsep=3pt%
  \foreach \val in {A,2,3,...,10,J,Q,K}{%
    \xsavebox{\val-\suit}{\mycard{\val}{\suit}{\suitcol}}%
  }%
}%
\xsavebox{K-vardiamond}{%
  \fboxsep=1.5pt\fboxrule=2pt\mycard{K}{vardiamond}{red}}%
%
%create layered array of cards: 13x4x52=2704 OCGs!
\foreach \j in {0,...,3}{%
  \foreach \i in {0,...,12}{%
    \fboxrule=0pt\fboxsep=3.5pt%
    \makebox[\widthof{\xusebox{K-vardiamond}}][l]{%
      \foreach \suit/\jj in {spadesuit/0,clubsuit/1,varheart/2,vardiamond/3}{%
        \foreach \val/\ii in {%
          A/0,2/1,3/2,4/3,5/4,6/5,7/6,8/7,9/8,10/9,J/10,Q/11,K/12}{%
          \xdef\tablePos{\the\numexpr\j*13+\i\relax}%
          \xdef\stackPos{\the\numexpr\jj*13+\ii\relax}%
          \begin{ocg}{\tablePos-\stackPos-card}{\tablePos-\stackPos-card}{%
            \expandafter\ifnum\numexpr\tablePos-\stackPos\relax=0 on%
            \else off\fi%
          }%
            \makebox[0pt][l]{\xusebox{\val-\suit}}%
          \end{ocg}%
        }%
      }%
    }~%
  }\\%
}\\[1ex]
\mediabutton[
  jsaction={riffle();update();}
]{\fbox{\strut Riffle}}
\mediabutton[
  jsaction={
    var myIntA=app.setInterval(
      'riffle();update();if(riffleCount\%10==0||order[0]==51)
        app.clearInterval(myIntA);',100);
  }
]{\fbox{\strut Riffle$\times$10}}
\mediabutton[
  jsaction={
    var myIntB=app.setInterval(
      'riffle();update();if(order[0]==51) app.clearInterval(myIntB);',100);
  }
]{\fbox{\strut Auto Riffle}}
\mediabutton[
  jsaction={reset();}
]{\fbox{\strut Reset}}

\end{document}
```

---

Original example without chart:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}

\usepackage{pgffor,color,calc}
\usepackage{media9} %\mediabutton
\usepackage{xsavebox,ocgx2}

%suit symbols from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9643
\DeclareSymbolFont{extraup}{U}{zavm}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varheart}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{86}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vardiamond}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{87}

%typesets playing card; args: value, suite, colour
\makeatletter
\def\mycard#1#2#3{%
  \fbox{\rule[-4ex]{0pt}{5ex}\makebox[3.5ex][l]{#1$\color{#3}\@nameuse{#2}$}}}
\makeatother

%initialisations (JavaScript) on page-open (/O <<...>>)
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex\def\pdfpageattr{\pdfvariable pageattr}\fi
\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup
  \pdfpageattr{
    \the\pdfpageattr
    /AA << /O << /S/JavaScript /JS (%
      console.show();
      console.clear();
      %card[<table position>][<stack position>]
      var card=new Array(52);
      for(var i=0;i<52;i++){card[i]=new Array(52);}
      ocg=this.getOCGs(this.pageNum);
      for(var i in ocg){
        ocgName=ocg[i].name.split('-');
        card[ocgName[0]][ocgName[1]]=ocg[i];
      }%
      %initial order
      var order=new Array(52);
      var oldOrder=new Array(52);
      for(i=0;i<52;i++) order[i]=i;
      var riffleCount=0;
      %riffle top card
      var riffle=function(){
        for(i=0;i<52;i++) oldOrder[i]=order[i];
        if(order[0]!=51){
          %remove current card from top
          var top=order.shift();
          %insert `top' at new random position
          order.splice(1+Math.random()*order.length, 0, top);
          console.println(++riffleCount);
        }
      };
      var update=function(){
        %update OCG visibility
        for(tablePos=0;tablePos<52;tablePos++){
          card[tablePos][oldOrder[tablePos]].state=false;
          card[tablePos][order[tablePos]].state=true;
        }
      };
      var reset=function(){
        for(i=0;i<52;i++) {oldOrder[i]=order[i]; order[i]=i;}
        update(); riffleCount=0;
        console.clear();
      };
    ) >> >>
  }
}
\x

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}\parindent=0pt%
%
%typeset playing cards into xsaveboxes
\foreach \suit/\suitcol in {%
  spadesuit/black,clubsuit/black,varheart/red,vardiamond/red}{%
  \fboxrule=0.5pt\fboxsep=3pt%
  \foreach \val in {A,2,3,...,10,J,Q,K}{%
    \xsavebox{\val-\suit}{\mycard{\val}{\suit}{\suitcol}}%
  }%
}%
\xsavebox{K-vardiamond}{%
  \fboxsep=1.5pt\fboxrule=2pt\mycard{K}{vardiamond}{red}}%
%
%create layered array of cards: 13x4x52=2704 OCGs!
\foreach \j in {0,...,3}{%
  \foreach \i in {0,...,12}{%
    \fboxrule=0pt\fboxsep=3.5pt%
    \makebox[\widthof{\xusebox{K-vardiamond}}][l]{%
      \foreach \suit/\jj in {spadesuit/0,clubsuit/1,varheart/2,vardiamond/3}{%
        \foreach \val/\ii in {%
          A/0,2/1,3/2,4/3,5/4,6/5,7/6,8/7,9/8,10/9,J/10,Q/11,K/12}{%
          \xdef\tablePos{\the\numexpr\j*13+\i\relax}%
          \xdef\stackPos{\the\numexpr\jj*13+\ii\relax}%
          \begin{ocg}{\tablePos-\stackPos}{\tablePos-\stackPos}{%
            \expandafter\ifnum\numexpr\tablePos-\stackPos\relax=0 on%
            \else off\fi%
          }%
            \makebox[0pt][l]{\xusebox{\val-\suit}}%
          \end{ocg}%
        }%
      }%
    }~%
  }\\%
}\\[1ex]
\mediabutton[
  jsaction={riffle();update();}
]{\fbox{\strut Riffle}}
\mediabutton[
  jsaction={
    var myIntA=app.setInterval(
      'riffle();update();if(riffleCount\%10==0||order[0]==51)
        app.clearInterval(myIntA);',100);
  }
]{\fbox{\strut Riffle$\times$10}}
\mediabutton[
  jsaction={
    var myIntA=app.setInterval(
      'riffle();update();if(order[0]==51) app.clearInterval(myIntA);',100);
  }
]{\fbox{\strut Auto Riffle}}
\mediabutton[
  jsaction={reset();}
]{\fbox{\strut Reset}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: WOW, nice! And what about the other .js that there is in the website? Could you do the same?

Comment: @idriskameni I have extended the example to add a chart similar to the HTML example.