# Drawing Super Mario Bros.....in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, asymptote, fun

There are several questions about TeX.SE. that concern designs for recurrences such as fireworks, lunar calendar, the pi-greek, and into my mind I'm remembering a protagonist of an old video game: **Super Mario Bros**.

But is it possible to make detailed drawings of the protagonists of video games with LaTeX?

I'm just curious to see only how the users build Super Mario Bros. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Why would you do that in TeX?

Comment: @cfr cwac! Miss you!

Comment: There is a recent LaTeX codegolf answer that outputs Super Mario ASCII art that may be of interest [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/192737/32604).

Comment: @PauloCereda Cwac!

Comment: As you Know my answer is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444917/the-tikz-game-package-a-tex-sx-project/445383#445383).

Comment: I need to think of questions like these to get my reputation boosted....

Comment: @cfr For no personal reason, or personal use. Just a curiosity.

Comment: @vipa With all the sincerity possible I absolutely have not remembered your answer and the comments that I have left you.

Comment: @cfr I have a letter somewhere from DEK where he comments in passing that TeX is Turing complete so anything computable could be done in TeX (within the limitations of memory). Andrew Marc Greene actually wrote a Basic interpreter in TeX.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

What if Mario and Luigi are going to a party? Somebody said that they love ducks!!

[image]

[From The TikZducks package](https://github.com/samcarter/tikzducks)

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\newcommand{\superstripes}{\stripes[color=blue!80!black,width=3,height=1.0,rotate=5] \stripes[color=blue!80!black,width=0.1,rotate=0,distance=0.7,initialx=-1.1,height=2]}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck[tshirt=red!80!black,peakedcap=red!80!black,stripes={\superstripes}]
\fill[white] (0.8,2) circle (0.13);
\node[red!80!black,rotate=-25] at (0.8,2) {\scalebox
{0.6}{\textsf{M}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck[tshirt=green!70!black,peakedcap=green!70!black,
stripes={\superstripes}]
\fill[white] (0.8,2) circle (0.13);
\node[green!70!black,rotate=-25] at (0.8,2) {\scalebox
{0.6}{\textsf{L}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seeing the question, I felt confident that `tikzducks` would be rolled out.  You did not disappoint.

Comment: Thank you for your invaluable cooperation and your collaboration.

Comment: @Sebastiano, you are welcome.

Answer (score 120):

As [everyone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario_Bros.) knows, the game was released in 1985, and at that time LaTeX was just making it out into the world and there was no such thing as pdfTeX, let alone Ti*k*Z and other fancy systems, so what Nintendo had to make the pictures was Knuth's TeX only.

They needed an efficient way to make the pictures, so they obviously didn't have the time to write all those coordinates, so they resorted to a syntax which was easy to draw each frame of the game, like this:

```
\beginmario
..=====....
.=========.
.---@@-@...
-@-@@@-@@@.
-@--@@@-@@@
--@@@@----.
..@@@@@@@..
.==+===....
===+==+===.
===++++====
@=+@++@+=@@
@@++++++@@@
@++++++++@@
.+++..+++..
---....---.
---....----
\endmario
```

to produce:

> [image]

So they used something like this:

```
\input color.tex
\newtoks\marioactives
\def\newmariocolor#1#2#3{%
  \definecolor{M#2}{rgb}{#3}%
  \expandafter\def\csname MarioSquare#1\endcsname
    {\begingroup\color{M#2}\MarioBox}%
  \marioactives\expandafter{\the\marioactives\mkactive{#1}}}
\newdimen\unitlength
\newdimen\rulesize
\newcount\therow
\newcount\thecol
\def\MarioBox{\leavevmode\raise\therow\unitlength
  \hbox to 0pt{\kern\thecol\unitlength\DrawBox\hss}%
  \endgroup\advance\thecol 1 \ignorespaces}
\def\DrawBox{\leavevmode\hbox{\vrule width\rulesize height\rulesize}}
\def\mkactive#1{%
  \catcode`#1=13\relax
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\lowercase{\endgroup
  \expandafter\let\expandafter~}\csname MarioSquare#1\endcsname}
{\catcode`\^^M=13
\gdef\beginmario{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\ =9
  \catcode`\^^M=13
  \def^^M{\advance\therow-1 \thecol 0 }%
  \rulesize\unitlength
  \advance\rulesize 0.1pt
  \the\marioactives}%
  \gdef\endmario{\endgroup}%
}

\newmariocolor{=}{red}{1,0,0}
\newmariocolor{+}{blue}{0,0.15,1}
\newmariocolor{@}{yellow}{1,0.65,0}
\newmariocolor{-}{brown}{0.5,0.1,0}
\newmariocolor{.}{white}{1,1,1}
\unitlength=5pt

\beginmario
..=====....
.=========.
.---@@-@...
-@-@@@-@@@.
-@--@@@-@@@
--@@@@----.
..@@@@@@@..
.==+===....
===+==+===.
===++++====
@=+@++@+=@@
@@++++++@@@
@++++++++@@
.+++..+++..
---....---.
---....----
\endmario

\bye
```

Comment: Unbelievable!!!! Did you already known this solution, right? Or did you create this just now?

Comment: @Sigur I never worked for Nintendo, if that's what you're asking ;-) (yes, I wrote it now :-)

Comment: Ow, I was asking the second. Amazing how fast you wrote the code. Congs.

Comment: @Sigur Actually the `\MarioBox` above is a modified version of LaTeX's `\put`, and `\DrawBox` is almost the same as `\rule`. The rest are funny catcode settings to obfuscate the code ;-)

Comment: Simply excellent the story... and the code.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks, glad you liked. However my answer already received far too many votes. Could you please accept one of the other answers?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Generally, I always listen to people who are prepared, educated, and wise. Okay :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you :-)

Answer (score 28):

Like Sigur, I am also convinced this is an XY question. Probably Italian autocorrection replaced marmot my Mario, right? ;-)

```
\documentclass[border={1cm 3.14mm 1cm 3.14mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzlings} % https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzlings
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \marmot[whiskers,teeth,3D,shadow]
 \fill[top color=blue!70,bottom color=blue,shading angle=-30] 
 (-0.56,1.35) to[out=-10,in=190] (0.56,1.35) 
 to[out=-80,in=85] (0.58,0.6) to[out=-175,in=-5] (-0.58,0.6) 
  to[out=95,in=-100] cycle;
 \shade[ball color=brown!50!black,rotate around={70:(0.385,0.93)}] (0.385,0.93) ellipse (0.24 and 0.13);
 \shade[ball color=brown!50!black,rotate around={-70:(-0.385,0.93)}] (-0.385,0.93) ellipse (0.24 and 0.13);
 \draw[red,thick,fill=yellow] (-0.1,1.2) -- (-0.25,1.05) -- (0,0.7) -- (0.25,1.05) --
  (0.1,1.2) -- cycle;
 \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries,text=red] at (0,1) {S};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I expected reply from you....and you fulfilled....Great....

Comment: Put a raccoon tail on it and it might look like Mario in the tanuki suit as seen in Super Mario Bros. 3.

Answer (score 14):

With `ducksay` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ducksay}

\AddAnimal{luigi}
{
         ,-"-.
        /     :
       '   ,- |
       |  | L|---.
      .   `,'     |
      |   / _  _  |
     ,|  /."_ "."/
    | ' :  ( || |
     \  |b  D| b|.-.
      ,--8b     "   )
      | _     d._ -'
      '. `    YCGMMP
        ""\    " |"
           \    /
            |__|
}

\begin{document}

\ducksay[animal=luigi]{I'm luigi}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wait, someone (except me) posted a `ducksay` answer, and I completely missed it! Great answer!

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly Mario, but close enough. You'll need to download the [Super Mario 256](https://www.dafont.com/super-mario-256.font) font and compile this with XeTeX or LuaTeX.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{relsize}
\newfontfamily\mario{SuperMario256.ttf}
\newcommand\marioltr[2]{{%
  \mario \sbox0{#1}\sbox2{\larger#1}%
  \dimen0=\dimexpr(\wd2-\wd0)/2\relax
  \dimen2=\dimexpr\ht2-\ht0\relax
  \leavevmode \kern-\dimen0\lower\dimen2 \rlap{\unhbox2}\kern \dimen0
  \textcolor{#2}{#1}}}
\newcommand\textmario[2]{%
  \textmarioAUX#1{}\relax\textmarioAUXX#2{}\relax\stop}
\newcommand\textmarioAUX{}
\def\textmarioAUX#1#2\textmarioAUXX#3#4\stop{%
  \stopifempty{#1}\stopifempty{#3}%
  \marioltr{#1}{#3}\textmarioAUX#2\textmarioAUXX#4\stop}
\newcommand\stopifempty[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\stopmario\fi}
\newcommand\stopmario{}
\def\stopmario#1\stop{\fi}
\newcommand\mariologo{{%
  \sbox0{\textmario{SUPER}{byrgy}}%
  \sbox2{\larger\textmario{MARIO}{rgybg}}%
  \dimen0=\dimexpr(\wd2-\wd0)/2\relax
  \leavevmode \vbox {\hsize=\wd2 \parindent=0pt
    \leavevmode \kern\dimen0 \box0 \par\nointerlineskip
    \leavevmode \ht2=0.9\ht2 \box2}}}
\newcommand\makeHTMLcolors[1]{%
  \ifx\relax#1 \else\expandafter\makeHTMLcolorAUX \fi{#1}}
\newcommand\makeHTMLcolorAUX[2]{\definecolor{#1}{HTML}{#2}\makeHTMLcolors}
\makeHTMLcolors b{049CD8}y{FBD000}r{E52521}g{43B047}\relax
\begin{document}
\mariologo
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow...thank you so much...for a happy new year...and for your nice answer. Thank you very much again.

Comment: You're welcome @Sebastiano! I fixed the code: the previous version had some problems when using the logo inline with other text

Answer (score 7):

Utilizing the newly released `pxpic` package, and recreating something from a [lovely old post by Paulo Cereda](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63759/117050), the following adds Yoshi and his long tongue as a better alternative to `\hspace` and `\hfill`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.14,preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{pxpic}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\yoshi@drawhead[1]
  {%
    \pxpic
      [
        mode=px,
        size={#1},
        skip=0,
        colors =
          {
             d=[HTML]{380a00} % dark red from hat border
            ,v=[HTML]{ae2e5f} % violet from within hat
            ,p=[HTML]{f63b70} % pink from within hat
            ,B=[HTML]{8f4546} % ugly violet brown from within hat
            ,P=[HTML]{ba554d} % strange pastel pink from within hat
            ,G=[HTML]{a7b23a} % dirt green from top right of hat
            ,O=[HTML]{d6a433} % dirt orange from top right of hat
            ,Y=[HTML]{f3d563} % dirt yellow from top right of hat
            ,s=[HTML]{f1c7b7} % skin
            ,S=[HTML]{fa6a62} % dark skin
            ,b=[HTML]{815e1a} % brown from ear
            ,1=[HTML]{314369} % dark blue from trousers
            ,2=[HTML]{49819a} % navy blue from trousers
            ,3=[HTML]{88d5c5} % bright blue from trousers
            ,4=[HTML]{293581} % dark saturated blue from trousers
            ,5=[HTML]{42766a} % teal from trousers
            ,o=[HTML]{ed8603} % yoshi orange
            ,.=[HTML]{00f502} % yoshi bright green
            ,:=[HTML]{0db710} % yoshi middle green
            ,;=[HTML]{077208} % yoshi dark green
            ,"=[HTML]{f6f5fa} % gloves white
            ,t=[HTML]{b42e09} % tongue
            ,k=black
            ,w=white
          }
      ]
      {
        {0000000dddd}
        {00000ddPppGd}
        {000ddPpvvOYd}
        {00dPpvvkkkkkkk}
        {0dPvvkkkkkkkkkk}
        {0dvvskkSSk}
        {dBvsbskssk0bbb}
        {dvvSbskksssss0b00000000000kkkk}
        {dBvdSsksskSSbbb0000kkk00kk....k}
        {0ddkdSsskkkb""b000k:.;kk....ww.k}
        {00kkdddddddb""b000k:;ww...k...wk}
        {00012dvvpppb"0b000k;wwwk.....::k}
        {001522dvvvvBbb0000k;wwwk....:kk}
        {0012222ddddd0000000kwwww...:k}
        {001222223ww4kk000kkokww:..:k}
        {00122222223kYkkk0okok;:..:k}
        {0kk44222224kbkkokkkk:....tt}
        {0k:kw44444kbkkkkk:......wtt}
        {00kwkwkkkkkbkk;;;.....wwwk}
        {00kwkwwwwwkkk::::wwwwwwwwk}
        {00k;wkkkkkkokwkkw;kkkk;ww;kk}
        {000kwk":::kookookk0000kk;ww;k}
        {000kwkkkkkkkooook0000000kkkkk}
        {000k;ktttttkkookk}
        {0000kkttttt"kkkk}
        {00000kttttttk}
        {00000kkkkkkkk}
      }%
  }
\newcommand*\yoshi@drawtonguetip[1]
  {%
    \pxpic
      [
        mode=px,
        size={#1},
        skip=0,
        colors =
          {
             o=[HTML]{ed8603} % yoshi orange
            ,t=[HTML]{b42e09} % tongue
            ,k=black
          }
      ]
      {
        {00tttt}
        {tttoott}
        {tttooot}
        {tttttot}
        {ttttttt}
        {00tttt}
      }%
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\yoshi@drawtongue{O{#2} m}
  {%
    \pxpic
      [
        mode=px,
        ht={#2},
        wd={#1},
        colors = {t=[HTML]{b42e09}}
      ]
      {tt}%
  }
\newcommand\yoshifill[1][1pt]
  {%
    \leavevmode
    \yoshi@drawhead{#1}\nobreak
    \hskip-5\dimexpr#1\relax
    \xleaders\hbox{\raise9\dimexpr#1\relax\yoshi@drawtongue[.01pt]{#1}}\hfill
    \nobreak
    \raise7\dimexpr#1\relax\yoshi@drawtonguetip{#1}%
  }
\newcommand\yoshiskip[2][1pt]
  {%
    \leavevmode
    \ifdim\dimexpr#2-34\dimexpr#1\relax<0pt
      \PackageWarning{yoshi}
        {%
          Yoshi is too big for your skip, put him on a diet.\MessageBreak
          O\expandafter\@gobble
        }%
      \rlap{\yoshiskip@{#1}{0pt}}%
      \hskip\dimexpr#2\relax
    \else
      \hbox{\yoshiskip@{#1}{#2-34\dimexpr#1\relax}}%
    \fi
  }
\newcommand\yoshiskip@[2]
  {%
    \yoshi@drawhead{#1}%
    \hskip-5\dimexpr#1\relax
    \raise9\dimexpr#1\relax\yoshi@drawtongue[#2]{#1}%
    \raise7\dimexpr#1\relax\yoshi@drawtonguetip{#1}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makebox[7cm][s]{Some text\yoshifill here}

\rule{7cm}{1pt}\\ % for comparison
\yoshiskip{7cm}

A\yoshiskip{30pt}bc\\ % yoshi is too big, we must put him on a diet!
A\yoshiskip[.5pt]{30pt}bc
\end{document}
```

---

Since ToCs are boring, and no one likes dotted lines, how about letting Yoshi help fetching those page numbers?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pxpic}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\yoshi@drawhead[1]
  {%
    \pxpic
      [
        mode=px,
        size={#1},
        skip=0,
        colors =
          {
             d=[HTML]{380a00} % dark red from hat border
            ,v=[HTML]{ae2e5f} % violet from within hat
            ,p=[HTML]{f63b70} % pink from within hat
            ,B=[HTML]{8f4546} % ugly violet brown from within hat
            ,P=[HTML]{ba554d} % strange pastel pink from within hat
            ,G=[HTML]{a7b23a} % dirt green from top right of hat
            ,O=[HTML]{d6a433} % dirt orange from top right of hat
            ,Y=[HTML]{f3d563} % dirt yellow from top right of hat
            ,s=[HTML]{f1c7b7} % skin
            ,S=[HTML]{fa6a62} % dark skin
            ,b=[HTML]{815e1a} % brown from ear
            ,1=[HTML]{314369} % dark blue from trousers
            ,2=[HTML]{49819a} % navy blue from trousers
            ,3=[HTML]{88d5c5} % bright blue from trousers
            ,4=[HTML]{293581} % dark saturated blue from trousers
            ,5=[HTML]{42766a} % teal from trousers
            ,o=[HTML]{ed8603} % yoshi orange
            ,.=[HTML]{00f502} % yoshi bright green
            ,:=[HTML]{0db710} % yoshi middle green
            ,;=[HTML]{077208} % yoshi dark green
            ,"=[HTML]{f6f5fa} % gloves white
            ,t=[HTML]{b42e09} % tongue
            ,k=black
            ,w=white
          }
      ]
      {
        {0000000dddd}
        {00000ddPppGd}
        {000ddPpvvOYd}
        {00dPpvvkkkkkkk}
        {0dPvvkkkkkkkkkk}
        {0dvvskkSSk}
        {dBvsbskssk0bbb}
        {dvvSbskksssss0b00000000000kkkk}
        {dBvdSsksskSSbbb0000kkk00kk....k}
        {0ddkdSsskkkb""b000k:.;kk....ww.k}
        {00kkdddddddb""b000k:;ww...k...wk}
        {00012dvvpppb"0b000k;wwwk.....::k}
        {001522dvvvvBbb0000k;wwwk....:kk}
        {0012222ddddd0000000kwwww...:k}
        {001222223ww4kk000kkokww:..:k}
        {00122222223kYkkk0okok;:..:k}
        {0kk44222224kbkkokkkk:....tt}
        {0k:kw44444kbkkkkk:......wtt}
        {00kwkwkkkkkbkk;;;.....wwwk}
        {00kwkwwwwwkkk::::wwwwwwwwk}
        {00k;wkkkkkkokwkkw;kkkk;ww;kk}
        {000kwk":::kookookk0000kk;ww;k}
        {000kwkkkkkkkooook0000000kkkkk}
        {000k;ktttttkkookk}
        {0000kkttttt"kkkk}
        {00000kttttttk}
        {00000kkkkkkkk}
      }%
  }
\newcommand*\yoshi@drawtonguetip[1]
  {%
    \pxpic
      [
        mode=px,
        size={#1},
        skip=0,
        colors =
          {
             o=[HTML]{ed8603} % yoshi orange
            ,t=[HTML]{b42e09} % tongue
            ,k=black
          }
      ]
      {
        {00tttt}
        {tttoott}
        {tttooot}
        {tttttot}
        {ttttttt}
        {00tttt}
      }%
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\yoshi@drawtongue{O{#2} m}
  {%
    \pxpic
      [
        mode=px,
        ht={#2},
        wd={#1},
        colors = {t=[HTML]{b42e09}}
      ]
      {tt}%
  }
\newcommand\yoshifill[1][1pt]
  {%
    \leavevmode
    \yoshi@drawhead{#1}\nobreak
    \hskip-5\dimexpr#1\relax
    \xleaders\hbox{\raise9\dimexpr#1\relax\yoshi@drawtongue[.01pt]{#1}}\hfill
    \nobreak
    \raise7\dimexpr#1\relax\yoshi@drawtonguetip{#1}%
  }
\newcommand\yoshiskip[2][1pt]
  {%
    \leavevmode
    \ifdim\dimexpr#2-34\dimexpr#1\relax<0pt
      \PackageWarning{yoshi}
        {%
          Yoshi is too big for your skip, put him on a diet.\MessageBreak
          O\expandafter\@gobble
        }%
      \rlap{\yoshiskip@{#1}{0pt}}%
      \hskip\dimexpr#2\relax
    \else
      \hbox{\yoshiskip@{#1}{#2-34\dimexpr#1\relax}}%
    \fi
  }
\newcommand\yoshiskip@[2]
  {%
    \yoshi@drawhead{#1}%
    \hskip-5\dimexpr#1\relax
    \raise9\dimexpr#1\relax\yoshi@drawtongue[#2]{#1}%
    \raise7\dimexpr#1\relax\yoshi@drawtonguetip{#1}%
  }

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\@dottedtocline
  {\leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern\@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern\@dotsep mu$}\hfill}
  {\yoshifill[.06ex]}
  {}
  {\GenericError{}{Patching gone wrong}{}{}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\duckument[toc]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: aahhah very beautiful and I see a long code....For me it is impossible to do this code. Many compliments and thank youuuuuuuu. :-) +1

Comment: @Sebastiano well, substract everything that's inside of the arguments of `\pxpic` and you see how long the real code is :)

Answer (score 6):

As a fan I have to contribute to this.
It is a rather simple soltution, but gets the job done.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}
    
    \definecolor{skin}{RGB}{251,206,177}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfsetplotmarksize{3.3ex}
        
        %\foreach \x in {0,1,2,...,12}
        %\foreach \y in {0,1,2,...,18}
        %\draw (\x,\y) rectangle (1,1);
        
        %red trouseres
        \node[red] at (2.5,3.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (3.5,3.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (4.5,3.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[red] at (7.5,3.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (8.5,3.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (9.5,3.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[red] at (2.5,4.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (3.5,4.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (4.5,4.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (5.5,4.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (6.5,4.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (7.5,4.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (8.5,4.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (9.5,4.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[red] at (3.5,5.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (4.5,5.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (5.5,5.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (6.5,5.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (7.5,5.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (8.5,5.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[red] at (3.5,6.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[red] at (5.5,6.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (6.5,6.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[red] at (8.5,6.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};

        \node[red] at (4.5,7.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (5.5,7.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (6.5,7.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (7.5,7.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[red] at (4.5,8.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (7.5,8.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[red] at (4.5,9.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        %\node[red] at (7.5,9.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        %red cap
        \node[red] at (2.5,15.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (3.5,15.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (4.5,15.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (5.5,15.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (6.5,15.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (7.5,15.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (8.5,15.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (9.5,15.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[red] at (3.5,16.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (4.5,16.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (5.5,16.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[red] at (6.5,16.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        %olive shirt
        \node[olive] at (2.5,6.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[olive] at (.5,7.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (1.5,7.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (2.5,7.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (3.5,7.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[olive] at (1.5,8.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (2.5,8.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (3.5,8.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (2.5,9.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (3.5,9.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[olive] at (5.5,8.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (6.5,8.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (5.5,9.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (6.5,9.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        
        \node[olive] at (9.5,6.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[olive] at (8.5,7.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (9.5,7.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (10.5,7.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (11.5,7.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[olive] at (8.5,8.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (9.5,8.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (10.5,8.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        %\node[olive] at (8.5,9.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        %\node[olive] at (9.5,9.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[olive] at (7.5,9.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        %olive feet
        \node[olive] at (.5,1.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (1.5,1.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (2.5,1.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (3.5,1.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[olive] at (8.5,1.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (9.5,1.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (10.5,1.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (11.5,1.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[olive] at (1.5,2.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (2.5,2.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (3.5,2.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[olive] at (8.5,2.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (9.5,2.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (10.5,2.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        %skin knots
        \node[skin] at (4.5,6.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (7.5,6.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        %skin face
        \node[skin] at (3.5,10.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (4.5,10.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (5.5,10.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (6.5,10.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (7.5,10.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (8.5,10.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (9.5,10.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[skin] at (3.5,11.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (4.5,11.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (5.5,11.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (6.5,11.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[skin] at (5.5,14.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (6.5,14.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[skin] at (2.5,13.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (2.5,12.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[skin] at (4.5,13.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (5.5,13.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (6.5,13.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[skin] at (2.5,12.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (5.5,12.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (6.5,12.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (7.5,12.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[skin] at (8.5,14.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (8.5,13.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (9.5,13.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (10.5,13.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};

        \node[skin] at (9.5,12.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (10.5,12.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (11.5,12.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        %skin hands
        \node[skin] at (0.5,4.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (0.5,5.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (0.5,6.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (1.5,4.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (1.5,5.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (1.5,6.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (2.5,5.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[skin] at (10.5,4.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (10.5,5.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (10.5,6.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (9.5,5.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (11.5,4.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (11.5,5.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[skin] at (11.5,6.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
    
        %olive face and beard
        \node[olive] at (7.5,11.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (8.5,11.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (9.5,11.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (10.5,11.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (8.5,12.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[olive] at (7.5,13.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (7.5,14.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[olive] at (2.5,11.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (1.5,11.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (1.5,12.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (1.5,13.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
        \node[olive] at (2.5,14.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (3.5,14.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (4.5,14.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (3.5,13.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (3.5,12.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        \node[olive] at (4.5,12.5) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can reduce your code with [this method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157127/14500).

Comment: @Paul Gaborit. Thanks I will try that.

Comment: I love it. It´s great to draw pixel graphics!...Is there a posibility to get rid of the black grid?

Comment: Dearest Roland, in truth these days I thought of you when I saw your avatar changed. In fact I wished, I am also a Super Mario fan, that you could put a reply. I thank you very much because each time reminds me of beautiful and carefree times. A cordial greeting and happy holidays and wishes.

Comment: @ sebastiano. For you too happy holidays and all the best in the new year.