# Put text anywhere at the document

Tags: floats, positioning, layers

I am wondering whether it is possible to position any object like text or image on top or behind the existing text in the document without affecting it?

That is to say, make an object float like a new layer in image editor.

Comment: You can do this for example with the eso-pic package. But with tikz layers are possible too.

Comment: You mean like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67656/are-there-other-fun-packages-like-the-coffee-stains-package ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A small `tikz` example:

[image: Page]

with this piece of code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[blue, fill=blue!20, fill opacity=0.7]
        (current page.center) circle (3cm)
        node {Blue circle behind text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[3]

\lipsum[9]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[red, fill=red!20, fill opacity=0.7]
        ($(current page.north)+(0,-4)$) circle (3cm)
        node {Red circle in front of text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```