# Tikz : texture cube faces using png image

Tags: tikz-pgf, png

I would like to draw a cube using Tikz with some faces of the cube having a texture on it (texture would be a PNG image)

my current code is at follows :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}
\tikzset{persp/.style={scale=3.0,x={(-0.8cm,-0.4cm)},y={(0.8cm,-0.4cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}},points/.style={fill=white,draw=black,thick}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[persp]\def\i{-15}
    \pgfmathparse{cos(\i)}\let\ci\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{sin(\i)}\let\si\pgfmathresult 
    \coordinate (Ocube) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (Xcube) at (\ci,\si,0);
    \coordinate (Ycube) at (-\si,\ci,0);
    \coordinate (Zcube) at (0,0,1);
    \coordinate (C0) at ($(Ocube)-(Xcube)-(Ycube)-(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (C1) at ($(Ocube)+(Xcube)-(Ycube)-(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (C2) at ($(Ocube)-(Xcube)+(Ycube)-(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (C3) at ($(Ocube)+(Xcube)+(Ycube)-(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (C4) at ($(Ocube)-(Xcube)-(Ycube)+(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (C5) at ($(Ocube)+(Xcube)-(Ycube)+(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (C6) at ($(Ocube)-(Xcube)+(Ycube)+(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (C7) at ($(Ocube)+(Xcube)+(Ycube)+(Zcube)$);
    \fill[black!20, draw=black, dashed,opacity=0.3] (C0)--(C1)--(C3)--(C2)--cycle;
    \fill[black!20, draw=black, dashed,opacity=0.3] (C0)--(C1)--(C5)--(C4)--cycle;
    \fill[black!20, draw=black, dashed,opacity=0.3] (C0)--(C2)--(C6)--(C4)--cycle;
    \fill[black!20, draw=black, thick,opacity=0.3] (C4)--(C5)--(C7)--(C6)--cycle;
    \fill[black!20, draw=black, thick,opacity=0.3] (C2)--(C3)--(C7)--(C6)--cycle;
    \fill[black!20, draw=black, thick,opacity=0.3] (C1)--(C3)--(C7)--(C5)--cycle;   
    \coordinate (Q0) at ($(Ocube)-.8*(Xcube)+(Ycube)-.8*(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (Q1) at ($(Ocube)+.8*(Xcube)+(Ycube)-.8*(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (Q2) at ($(Ocube)-.8*(Xcube)+(Ycube)+.8*(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (Q3) at ($(Ocube)+.8*(Xcube)+(Ycube)+.8*(Zcube)$);
    \fill[white!20, draw=black, thick,opacity=0.3] (Q0)--(Q1)--(Q3)--(Q2)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

On the last line, rather then filling white a color (white!20), I would like to draw the image "face.png". This drawing must be distorded so to fit the face realisticaly.

Could someone help me doing that ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I juste edited my code, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly an answer to the question, but it is fun.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[yellow,yslant=0.5] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
  \node[yslant=0.5,anchor=center,opacity=0.3]  at (1,1.5) {\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image-a}};
  \draw[magenta,yslant=-0.5] (-2,2) rectangle (0,0);
  \node[yslant=-0.5,anchor=center,opacity=0.3]  at (-1,1.5) {\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image-b}};
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \draw[orange,yslant=-0.5] (0,2) rectangle (2,4);
  \node[yslant=-0.5,anchor=center,xshift=0cm,yshift=1cm,opacity=0.3]  at (1,1.5) {\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image-b}};
  \draw[green,yslant=0.5,,xshift=-2cm,yshift=2cm] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
  \node[yslant=0.5,anchor=center,xshift=-2cm,yshift=2cm,opacity=0.3]  at (1,1.5) {\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image-a}};
\draw[blue,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1] (-2,0) rectangle (0,2);
\node[yslant=-0.5,anchor=center,xshift=0cm,yshift=2cm,xslant=1,opacity=0.3]  at (-0,-1) {\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image-a}};
  \end{scope}
  \draw[red,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1] (-4,2) rectangle (-2,4);
\node[yslant=-0.5,anchor=center,xshift=0cm,yshift=4cm,xslant=1,opacity=0.3]  at (-0,-1) {\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image-a}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Some explanation text would have been welcom but I manage to make it work.
However, I had to manualy tweak yslant, and it's therefore not a good solution in as it doesnt adapt to my a variable based projection.

Comment: @Amxx That is why it is not an exact answer :) But this was the easiest.

Answer (score 5):

There are several questions on the site which address filling a shape with an image in TikZ, for example:

- [TikZ: Drawing regular hexagons with pictures inside](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155598/tikz-drawing-regular-hexagons-with-pictures-inside)
- [How to clip an external image inside an ellipse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154882/how-to-clip-an-external-image-inside-an-ellipse)

We can adapt those solutions to your 3D shape. We use `\clip` to restrict to the front square of the cube, then add the image, and finally we draw the border around it.

I’ve replaced the line:

```
\fill[white!20, draw=black, thick,opacity=0.3] (Q0)--(Q1)--(Q3)--(Q2)--cycle;
```

with

```
\def\frontsquare{(Q0)--(Q1)--(Q3)--(Q2)--cycle}

\begin{scope}
    \clip \frontsquare;
    \node {\includegraphics{grass.jpg}};
\end{scope}

\draw[black, thick] \frontsquare;
```

First I define `\frontsquare` to the area you want to fill. The `\clip` contained in the scope restricts everything else we draw to within that area, until `\end{scope}`. When I use `\includegraphics` to add an image, only the part of the image that is within the front square. The `\draw` command then adds a border.

This is what the resulting cube looks like:

[image]

and here’s the complete code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}
\tikzset{persp/.style={scale=3.0,x={(-0.8cm,-0.4cm)},y={(0.8cm,-0.4cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}},points/.style={fill=white,draw=black,thick}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[persp]\def\i{-15}
    \pgfmathparse{cos(\i)}\let\ci\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{sin(\i)}\let\si\pgfmathresult 
    \coordinate (Ocube) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (Xcube) at (\ci,\si,0);
    \coordinate (Ycube) at (-\si,\ci,0);
    \coordinate (Zcube) at (0,0,1);
    \coordinate (C0) at ($(Ocube)-(Xcube)-(Ycube)-(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (C1) at ($(Ocube)+(Xcube)-(Ycube)-(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (C2) at ($(Ocube)-(Xcube)+(Ycube)-(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (C3) at ($(Ocube)+(Xcube)+(Ycube)-(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (C4) at ($(Ocube)-(Xcube)-(Ycube)+(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (C5) at ($(Ocube)+(Xcube)-(Ycube)+(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (C6) at ($(Ocube)-(Xcube)+(Ycube)+(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (C7) at ($(Ocube)+(Xcube)+(Ycube)+(Zcube)$);
    \fill[black!20, draw=black, dashed,opacity=0.3] (C0)--(C1)--(C3)--(C2)--cycle;
    \fill[black!20, draw=black, dashed,opacity=0.3] (C0)--(C1)--(C5)--(C4)--cycle;
    \fill[black!20, draw=black, dashed,opacity=0.3] (C0)--(C2)--(C6)--(C4)--cycle;
    \fill[black!20, draw=black, thick,opacity=0.3] (C4)--(C5)--(C7)--(C6)--cycle;
    \fill[black!20, draw=black, thick,opacity=0.3] (C2)--(C3)--(C7)--(C6)--cycle;
    \fill[black!20, draw=black, thick,opacity=0.3] (C1)--(C3)--(C7)--(C5)--cycle;   
    \coordinate (Q0) at ($(Ocube)-.8*(Xcube)+(Ycube)-.8*(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (Q1) at ($(Ocube)+.8*(Xcube)+(Ycube)-.8*(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (Q2) at ($(Ocube)-.8*(Xcube)+(Ycube)+.8*(Zcube)$);
    \coordinate (Q3) at ($(Ocube)+.8*(Xcube)+(Ycube)+.8*(Zcube)$);

    \def\frontsquare{(Q0)--(Q1)--(Q3)--(Q2)--cycle}

    \begin{scope}
        \clip \frontsquare;
        \node {\includegraphics{grass.jpg}};
    \end{scope}

    \draw[black, thick] \frontsquare;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I saw such exemples, but they don't fit my needs as they just clip the image to the polygone.
In my case the image is a QRcode and i would like it to fit the square face which means distord it accordingly

Comment: @Amxx: Of course. I’ve picked a bad image: the grass doesn’t show the lack of perspective transform. Playing with the `tikz-3dplot` library might give a way to fix it, but I can’t think of one off the top of my head.

Comment: That's precisely what I'm looking for