# How do I add some "texture" to a tikz fill?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create something like this:

[image]

By filling a rectangle.

NOTE: Ignore the borders of the image, I just want to give that texture to a tikz rectangle.

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I have no idea in how to make random colors over the fill... I saw examples where you can place lines or stars

Comment: Maybe you could use $\pgfmathrnd$ (see the TikZ/PGF manual, section 90.2.6) to create random coordinates on which you draw the details of the papery pattern? At the end you can clip it with a path (which may be random as well).

Comment: I'll take a look... Hmm, is there a way to create a grain or noise effect over a fill?

Comment: As a short way, clip the texture image with rectangle: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167568/31034

Comment: But that means that I need an external image, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes you need :-(

Comment: Hmmm actually I wanted to do it with only tikz... With external imagen I can add the effect on photoshop

Comment: Do you know the [cicada principle](http://www.sitepoint.com/the-cicada-principle-and-why-it-matters-to-web-designers/)?

Comment: Wow, that's a nice math theory applied on images :D
I have to try it, but I thing it does not help with my question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A brute-force attempt with `pgfplots`: there are surely better ways. :-)

The "coarseness" of the texture can be adjusted using the `samples` key value. For this fine of a texture, LuaLaTeX must be used (dynamic memory allocation). For `samples=100` or fewer, any modern engine can be used.

```
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage{luatex85}%
}{}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  view={0}{90},
  hide axis=true,
  samples=200,
  colormap={papyrus}{
    cmyk(0cm)=(0.00,0.08,0.24,0); 
    cmyk(1cm)=(0.00,0.08,0.24,0.05)
  },
]
  \addplot3[surf,shader=interp] {rand};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's the effect I needed. I'll try it later :)

Comment: Hi Paul, I'm trying this minimal, but this show an error: !Package pgfkeys: Choice '1.12' unknown in key '/pgfplots/compat/labels'. Do you know what's going on?

Comment: @MrSelberg you probably have an older version of `pgfplots` installed than 1.12.

Comment: 2013.84.1.7svn29531-17.1.7-noarch. That's my version.

Comment: I'll install the latest. That's must be the problem. I'll coment in a while.

Comment: @MrSelberg this example probably doesn't require v1.12 (though I can't check at the moment); it's just a habit of mine to set `compat` to the version I used to create the answer. This avoids warnings and makes the answer "future-proof" in case the behavior/syntax changes in future versions. If I were you, I'd just try removing the `compat=1.12` before doing a bunch of other stuff to get `pgfplots` updated. Of course, it's not a bad idea to get updated, either. Just a matter of what's more important to you at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I tried it before (remove that line) did not work. But I solve the problem: I had an older version of the package. With the newest version everything is ok. :D