# Render a more realistic ice cream

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am still typsetting exams, and this time I want to see if I can manage to recreate an ice cream.

[image]

While my temporarily solution looks like this

[image]

The biggest problem is that my solution -- in lack of a better word -- looks *plain*. Is there some way to add some texture to the fill, and make it look slightly more realistic?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\definecolor{brownMedium}{HTML}{623d22}
\definecolor{brownLight}{HTML}{a78d7b}
\definecolor{brownDark}{HTML}{573722}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \edef\w{10} \edef\h{6}

        \begin{scope}[shift={(0,0.5)},scale=1.1]
            \draw[color=brownDark, fill=brownDark,thick] (0,\w) -- (0,0) -- (\w,0)  -- (\w,\w);
            \draw[color=brownDark, fill=brownDark, thick] (\w,\w) arc(0:180:0.5*\w);
        \end{scope}

        \draw[color=brownMedium, thick, fill=brownMedium] (0,\w) -- (0,0) -- (\w,0)  -- (\w,\w);
        \draw[color=brownMedium,thick, fill=brownMedium] (\w,\w) arc(0:180:0.5*\w);

        \draw[color = brownLight, fill=brownLight, thick] (0.65*\w,-\h) arc(0:-180:0.15*\w);
        \draw[fill=brownLight, color = brownLight, thick] (0.65*\w,0) -- (0.65*\w,-\h) --  (0.35*\w,-\h) -- (0.35*\w,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you could build on the answers to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334341/121799) or [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/475141/121799). Ti*k*Z is not necessarily made for this. (And you can't believe what happened when my fellow marmots saw the ice cream. ;-)

Comment: You might try a graphics editor.  TikZ is better at illustrations than realism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{brownMedium}{HTML}{623d22}
\definecolor{brownLight}{HTML}{a78d7b}
\definecolor{brownDark}{HTML}{573722}

%stick
\fill[brownLight] 
(-1,-3.17) -- (-1,-8.48) arc (-140:-39:1.2) -- (0.8,-3.16) --cycle;
%shadow
\fill[brownLight!95!black,rounded corners] 
(0.8,-3.15) -- (0.8,-3.9) -- (0.5,-4.3) -- (-0.8,-4.3) -- (-1,-4.1) -- (-1,-3.1);
%ice cream
\fill[brownDark] 
(-4.2,5.2) -- (-4.2,-3.1) -- (-3.96,-3.24) -- (3.26,-3.21) -- (3.86,-2.9) -- (3.84,5.8) .. controls (3.54,9.77) and (-3.4,10.05) .. cycle;
\fill[brownMedium]
(3.21,5.5) -- (3.26,-3.21) -- (-3.96,-3.24) -- (-4,5.5) .. controls (-2.2,10.1) and (2.41,9.1) .. cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ice Cream with some little improvement]