# Pencil effect in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, package-options, options

We assume that to have drawn a vector....

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz\draw[->,line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a pencil effect with `TikZ` as the picture below?

[image]

Comment: It can be done here it is not called "pencil effect", but "chalkboard texture": https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334341/chalkboard-texture-for-tikz-lines

Comment: Do you need an raster image or a vector image?

Comment: @hpekristiansen Looks more like chalk than pencil to me.

Comment: For me it looks exactly like your picture.

Comment: @Navaro Neither. It was just to see if there was an effect similar to a porous red pencil used in textures.

Comment: @hpekristiansen In all honesty I've seen the other options and I don't like them. Anyway, after three years there are simple options and not galactic codes? :-)

Comment: You could use inkscape filters: use tex Text extension to insert the tikz script to create the arrow, save to inkscape, and apply filters.

Comment: Does this question answer your problem? [Chalkboard texture for tikz lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334341/138900)

Comment: @AndréC 50% yes and 50 % no..also for a long code...I prefer short code if and when it is possible.

Comment: @Navaro Thank you very much for your suggestions on InkScape....

Comment: you could join https://chat.inkscape.org/ you will find a lot of people that could help you.

Comment: Follow-up idea, how to use xkcd (https://xkcd.com/) style?

Comment: @xxx--- What is this link? 8-)

Comment: @Sebastiano xkcd is this comic strip website, often containing jokes about research life. Matplotlib has xkcd support (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xkcd.html). It'll cool to have it in Tikz or other Latex packages.

Comment: @xxx--- Ah, now I have understood...my english language and comprension often it is not very good. :-(

Comment: No worries. Happy Texing and be safe during the global virus situation!

Comment: @xxx--- The same also for you and I hope for you all the best.