# Is there any "worn book" or "ancient book" style or can it be done with watermark?

Tags: books, book-design, watermark

My question is exactly what it means. 
Does exist something that makes bookstyle like worn, but without losing the quality; or even can a "worn book" be done with watermark?

Comment: Using a parchment image, as here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29458 ?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/222173 ?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67656/are-there-other-fun-packages-like-the-coffee-stains-package

Comment: Thank you for everyone's answers!!!