# Sandpaper-like page background

Tags: backgrounds

How can I add a background to the pages of my document as in this example?

[image]

Original source: http://www.tsengbooks.com/images/6176s.pdf

Comment: You need an image that has the size of the page. Then you can use the `background` package to include it to every page of your document.

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231947 ?

Answer (score 2):

Just grab some picture that has an appropriate size and use the `background` package to insert it into the background of your document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
    angle=0,
    scale=1,
    contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{paper-bg}}
}

\usepackage{lipsum} % to print some random text

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Image credit: [Unsplash/Olga Thelavart](https://unsplash.com/photos/vS3idIiYxX0))