# Tangent images to icosahedron face

Tags: pstricks, tikz-3dplot, tangent

I would like to plot images in a tangent plane to each face of an icosahedron. Something like in the image.
[image]

I have tried several approaches like:

[Tikz : texture cube faces using png image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167566/tikz-texture-cube-faces-using-png-image)

and example code from [page 169 of pst-solides3d documentation](https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-solides3d/doc/pst-solides3d-doc.pdf)

But the former is not an easy extrapolation to an icosahedron (at least for myself) and the latter uses eps images and I can't get around converting the images into the right format. It is like png2eps conversion produces images shifted when added to the faces.

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!