# Nail shape figure in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

Does anybody know how could I draw nails-like with `tikz`? Something like those [here](http://tillynailart.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/20131123-190937.jpg%3Fw%3D640%26h%3D349).

[image]

I thought this could be achieved using polygon something like the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,calendar,matrix,backgrounds,folding}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[nodes={draw, thick, fill=red!20,minimum size=1cm},
    row sep=0.3cm,column sep=0.5cm] {
\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=7] {};&
\node[star,star points=4] {};&
\node[star,star points=5,star point ratio=0.8] {};&
\node[star,star points=7,star point ratio=0.8] {};&
\node[star,star points=10] {};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link to an image of the shape you want to obtain?

Comment: Somethign like those: http://tillynailart.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/20131123-190937.jpg%3Fw%3D640%26h%3D349

Comment: Do you want to define shapes or do you just want to draw them?

Comment: I want to draw and color them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just used paths with rounded corners instead of polygons. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%Oval
\draw[rounded corners=5pt,line width=1pt,densely dashed] (.5,0)--(1,0)--(1,.7) arc (0:180:.5 and 1.5)--(0,0)--(.5,0);
\node at (.5,-.5) {Oval};
%Square
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
\draw[rounded corners=5pt,line width=1pt,densely dashed] (.5,0)--(1,0)--(1,2.2)--(0,2.2)--(0,0)--(.5,0);
\node at (.5,-.5) {Square};
\end{scope}
%Squoval
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\draw[rounded corners=10pt,line width=1pt,densely dashed] (.5,0)--(1,0)--(1,2.2)--(0,2.2)--(0,0)--(.5,0);
\node at (.5,-.5) {Squoval};
\end{scope}
%Round
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\draw[rounded corners=7pt,line width=1pt,densely dashed] (0,1.7)--(0,0)--(1,0)--(1,1.7);
\draw[line width=1pt,densely dashed] (1,1.7) arc (0:180:.5);
\node at (.5,-.5) {Round};
\end{scope}
%Stiletto
\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
\draw[rounded corners=9pt,line width=1pt,densely dashed] (.5,0)--(1,0)--(1,.7)--(.5,2.3)--(0,.7)--(0,0)--(.5,0);
\node at (.5,-.5) {Stiletto};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Had to do some tweaking to make the dashed lines look ok. To take care of some work for you, it may be useful to use `--cycle;` at the end of a path, instead of starting and ending in the middle of a smooth section, as I have. I tried using that, but the dashed lines and rounded corners caused me some problems. You can change how round the paths are by adjusting the `rounded corners=` parameter.

And to color them, just put in `fill=red` (for instance, for red) inside the square brackets of the `\draw` command, separating it from the other instructions with a comma `,`.

**Edit for picture fill:**

To put a picture in one of the shapes, use the `clip` command. For example, say you wanted some kittens inside the oval, and you have the picture `kittens.jpg` in the same directory as your `.tex` file. With everything else as before, inside the `tikzpicture` environment use the following code:

```
%Oval-picture
\begin{scope}
\clip[rounded corners=5pt] (.5,0)--(1,0)--(1,.7) arc (0:180:.5 and 1.5)--(0,0)--(.5,0);; 
\node at (.25,.7) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{kittens.jpg}}; 
\end{scope}
%Oval-path
\draw[rounded corners=5pt,line width=1pt,densely dashed] (.5,0)--(1,0)--(1,.7) arc (0:180:.5 and 1.5)--(0,0)--(.5,0);
\node at (.5,-.5) {Oval};
```

You can change the positioning (by adjusting the coordinates of the `\node`) and size (by adjusting the size of `width=`) of the picture easily. The result is this:

[image]

So all that you do is start a new `scope` environment for all that you want to be clipped, and use the same path that you have for the shape. To not lose the thickness of the path of the shape, do this before the shape is actually drawn.

Comment: That is really amazing, thanks a lot. Is it that difficult to plot an image inside of each shape?

Comment: What sort of image? And I think it won't be, since you can always scale and shift things with `TikZ`.

Comment: @user45367: Are you refering to something like [how-to-clip-an-external-image-inside-an-ellipse](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154882/how-to-clip-an-external-image-inside-an-ellipse) ?

Comment: Yes, fill the area with an image. Something like "fill=image".

Comment: I added some basic ideas on how to do that. Check my updated response.