# I want to change the shape of picture in Moderncv

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, moderncv

I want to add my institution logos to my CV but unfortunately they don't appear the shape of picture that I want. How should I edit the code to make the picture circle?  [image]

Comment: I download the code from [here](https://github.com/pernl/Moderncv-Classic), but the photo in the template is rectangle, not circle. I want to change the shape. Can you help me?

Comment: @xiaojidan: Is the image circular? If not, even if it's rectangular, you can just clip it to some circular boundary.

Comment: The image is rectangle. I want to change it into a circled one.@Werner

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193555 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154882

Comment: You can't ping people in questions/answers, I don't think. And you cannot anyway ping people who haven't participated in the current discussion.

Comment: If you need to post another question, please include code for a minimal document which can be compiled to reproduce the problem or situation you want help with. The question you asked here already has an answer, so it isn't really needed, but that won't always be the case (and you wouldn't need to ask if you knew it was already answered, so that isn't really relevant when asking, if you see what I mean).