# crop image in different shape

Tags: graphics

I have the below image. but I need to add this image in a different shape in a latex document.
[image]

I draw the shape using Microsoft word and herewith I added the shape. Can anyone help me to create an image shape like shown below.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch Thank you

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to clip an external image inside an ellipse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154882/5764); you just have to define the path along which you want to clip the content.

Comment: I tried and I could not make like this. Can you help me @Werner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an image that you want to trim/clip in a way that leaves it as a [convex polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polygon) (as is the case with your example), you can turn/trim/clip the image successively via [`adjustbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)'s `trim` and `clip` options. It's tedious, but doable.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\colorbox{green}{\includegraphics[width=10em]{example-image}}

\colorbox{green}{%
  \adjustbox{trim=35pt 0pt 18pt 37pt, clip}{%
    \adjustbox{angle=45}{%
      \adjustbox{trim=0pt 45pt 0pt 0pt, clip}{%
        \adjustbox{angle=-90}{%
          \adjustbox{trim=0pt 20pt 0pt 0pt, clip}{%
            \adjincludegraphics[width=10em,angle=-45]{example-image}%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\end{document}
```

The coloured boxes/background is just to show that the trimmed parts are transparent.

A Tikz path would be easier and more manageable, even for non-convex polygon trimming.

Comment: Thank you @werner