# How to crop the figure in a specific shape in latex using includegraphics or tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
% left
\includegraphics[trim={5cm 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}
% right
\includegraphics[trim={0 0 5cm 0},clip]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

This trims the figure, with the appropriate side,

Suppose I want crop the figure in a specific shape like circle, oval, star, how to do that?
for example, like in the following.

[image: s]

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19938/2552